# Should the site have an automatic word filter for titles?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, titles, quality-filter

Math.SE has a *problem* with titles. The percentage of questions with the redundant word *question* in the title is [highest on Stack Exchange, by far](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16406/). Plenty of titles consist of other [mostly useless words](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8781/).  We have  a nice [meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) on writing a good title, but nobody's got time for meta posts.

On Stack Overflow, the words *question*, *doubt*, *problem*, and *help* **cannot** be used in titles. They result in a pop-up message directing user to a post about writing a good title:

[image]

On Mathematics, *problem* has several legitimate uses (e.g., in differential equations), and *question* is legitimate in questions about [Minkowski's question mark function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski's_question_mark_function). Some other such cases may exist.  In view of the above, my proposal is to issue a *non-blocking* warning when the title contains one of [generally useless words](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8781/). More specifically:

> A question title under 40 characters containing one of the words "question", "problem", "doubt" and "help" is **very** likely to be bad, and should generate a warning.

Something like this already exists: if the title contains the word *you*, the following message is shown (it does not block the submission).

[image: you]

The message should be different, though:

> The title of your question may be insufficiently specific. See [Writing Good Titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144).

---

Clarification: the filter is intended for *main* site only, not for meta.

Comment: So if I would like to ask something like "Blabla's doubt regarding the solution of Whitehead's Problem" which may be a valid title is going to be banned?

Comment: IMHO, instead of a pop-up saying "strong discouraged", it will be more effective if it cost the user 'something' to use certain keyword. e.g. question : 2 point, doubt : 2 point, help : 5 point and homework : 100 points!

Comment: (I'm all in favor of automatic filtering titles; but I do think this needs to be discussed thoroughly before doing anything.)

Comment: What about "problem"?

Comment: @achillehui Unfortunately, many of posters of such titles have nothing to lose. (A related idea is to drop the word filter beyond some reputation level, which I think was floated at some point on meta.SO). Asaf: what about "what about "problem""? I addressed this word in the post.

Comment: No, I meant what about the "problem" problem in my suggested title referring to Whitehead's Problem? Even if you don't use the word "doubt", "Whitehead's Problem" is a name for a mathematical problem.

Comment: Other examples can be of the family of "What are some open problems in functional analysis that can be explained to undergrad students?"

Comment: Yeah, okay. This is a definitive proof that I am going to sleep.

Comment: This is only for the main site, right? For meta, we may need to mention such words in titles.

Comment: @900 Thanks. Probably most MSE users have no experience with how it works on SO, so it would be helpful to mention that explicitly in the question.

Comment: How would this handle a question about "Minkowski's Question Mark Function," for example? I would not support using the symbol "?" instead of "question mark" because it would be harder to search for and possibly confusing.

Comment: I got 7466 matches for "question" in the title --- when I searched MathSciNet, for reviews of mathematical research articles. 384 for "help", but only 43 for "doubt".

Comment: @GerryMyerson Demonstrating that mathematicians are generally bad in writing titles. "On a question of Erdős", "on a polynomial inequality", etc. I would edit those at once if they appeared on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: Please provide an email address, so I could contact you and make sure none of my titles are bad.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Just post the paper here prior to sending it to journal. Or instead of.

Comment: Please provide me the university you're currently sitting as the chair of the hiring committee, so when I submit my application with only one published paper (the one I published recently, before accepting this great advice), the committee will know why this is the situation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok, there's a warning now:

[image: The title of your question may be insufficiently specific.]

This is triggered by a title matching

```
^.{0,30}(^|\W)(anyone|difficult|doubt|easy|hard|help|interesting|please|problem|query|question|someone|stuck|very)(\W|$).{0,30}$
```

...so it heavily favors *short* titles - [Tricky integration/functions problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962480/tricky-integration-functions-problem) would've warned, while [Least squares problem equivalent to solving Poisson problem for graph embedding given edge lengths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962234/least-squares-problem-equivalent-to-solving-poisson-problem-for-graph-embedding) would not have.

Comment: Can this be enabled [elsewhere](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8831/169736)?

Comment: @Braiam You'll probably need another set of words for Ubuntu. The one in Shog9's answer came from a [community effort](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8781/) to identify signs of weak titles specific to this site.

Comment: Please add word boundaries when you get a chance: this warning is triggered by questions about *Hardy spaces* (matching "hard").

Comment: Done, @NormalHuman