# Autofilters for Hot Network Questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hot-questions-list

The SE software allows us to request certain regular expressions be automatically excluded from the Hot Network Questions.

I was asked by the CMs to make this post on the meta, and include the list. This way the community can express agreement or disagreement, as well as suggest improvements.

Let me start by stating that the goal is to filter out bad titles. If it happens that some good questions get filtered out, it is unfortunate, but the default state of a question is off the HNQ, and the current consensus of the moderators is that it is more important to keep questions which we do not want to represent our site off this list.

With that in mind, note that sometimes good questions have bad titles. I still hope that people will push to edit and improve titles of questions just as well as their bodies.

**One final clarification.** There will be a zero tolerance policy towards people who make titles worse just to get a question on or off the HNQ. People who abuse this list will be punished.

### Status of this thread: Discussion.

This thread is aimed to have a discussion phase (until April 30) $\to$ escalation phase $\to$ implementation stage.

---

- this
- problem
- question
- puzzle
- contest
- advice
- help
- please
- the following
- exercise
- easy
- opinion
- Solv[e|ing]
- difficult
- urgent
- tricky
- simplify

Comment: Candidates: "urgent", triple exclamation marks "!!!", "No clue".  Most importantly, "urgent" used in a title should keep that post out of the HNQ.  Also, I'd suggest we filter out titles including "easy".  I can't tell you how many posts are titled in a similar fashion to "Solving easy integral", or such.

Comment: I don't know if your post was an announcement, or intended for review/input from users here.  I assumed the latter.  If the former is the intention, they are all good suggestions to use for filtering posts from HNQ.

Comment: (Note, the inclusion by an OP requesting us to solve an "easy" problem (according to them) has always baffled me).  Of course, if a user is struggling with a question, I'd expect them to consider it "hard".

Comment: Also, any title including the word "opinion" ought to be filtered out, too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, amWhy, I've also clarified on the status of this thread. It is currently in a discussion phase. I've added "easy" and "difficult", as well as "opinion" and "solve/solving". I'm reluctant to add "hard" at the moment, but in my experience, usually bad titles that have "hard" will have other keywords from the list.

Comment: Great potential here, with the ability to filter out pre-specified words.  Thanks for your work in this undertaking, @Asaf, and for bringing the discussion to meta!

Comment: Please add "tricky" and "plz"

Comment: @rschwieb: I think "plz" should be added the to blacklist.

Comment: @Asaf  When your referred to the "blacklist" is that what "SmokeDetector alerts us to, like "Blacklisted word in title, few characters in body."  plz would be a great non-word to add to such a blacklist. Perhaps even "urgent".

Comment: @amWhy: By blacklist I refer to "it is impossible to actually post the question with this pattern in the title". (Such a blacklist was discussed before on meta.)

Comment: Thanks, @Asaf.  I imagine SE as a network, has included key typically offensive words to a black-list they include in their screens across the network (as well as screening repeated characters, etc.).

Comment: Here is a rather non-descript term used in 56K titles:  "Simplify".  See [search result here: Simplify](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Simplify).  (A lot of "Simplify boolean..., logic, surds, fractions, alg-precal-level algebra expressions...etc.)

Comment: @Asaf  In your current list, you've included "context"; did you perhaps mean "contest", and if not, I'd like to see any title using "contest" filtered from the HNQ.

Comment: Also, [here's my search results for titles including the word "stuck"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=stuck): 51K of them came up.

Comment: I notice there are currently no math questions on the hot network questions list. Why are we trying so hard to keep them off?

Comment: @MattSamuel  Probably because it tends to attract rather low-quality popular questions, usually made more popular by folks not terribly interested in math, but more interested in quizzes or puzzles posted on Facebook, and such. With such added attention, poor answers tend to come flooding in. (@Asaf could probably give exemplars of this phenomenon.   Plus, on SE, the network, anything with mathjax in the title, is filtered out from the HotNetwork Question list.

Comment: @MattSamuel I came up with such an example from days of yore:  [How long will it take Marie to saw another board into three pieces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379927/how-long-will-it-take-marie-to-saw-another-board-into-3-pieces?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top).  I think a lot of users on math.se would like more not to be known as a "riddle site," or an excuse for those with little interest in math, to bash teachers, mathematicians, etc.

Comment: @amWhy: Indeed, context should have been contest. Simplify is a good suggestion.

Comment: @MattSamuel  And since I mentioned some users' Facebook inspired question, I found [over 230 posts that actually mention Facebook in the title](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Facebook).  I'll leave it to you to discern their quality, overall.

Comment: @Matt: Questions that reach the HNQ tend to amass a lot of votes, sometimes these posts are great, and well-deserving of the votes. Often, they are not what we want to be a representation of mathematics on the broader SE community.

Comment: @amWhy  off topic. If you a native English speaker or if you have excellent English, is it possible to answer me with a little comment? What is the difference between the words Tricky and difficult? I "discovered" the word Tricky using this site. I didn't know before. For example, which one is used for an IMO question? IMO problems are difficult or IMO problems are tricky.  Or what is the difference tricky proof between difficult proof?   I see the word tricky a lot on this site. But google translate both translates the same to my mother tongue.. Thank you.

Comment: @lonestudent: Something is difficult if it's just hard to do for whatever reason. Something is tricky if you get the sense that it *should* be simpler, and that there's just some trick to it that you're not seeing. Admittedly, a lot of people use them interchangeably. (Caveat lector: I am *not* a native English speaker.)

Comment: "Tricky" is probably more off-putting that "difficult", because a lot of students refer to using "tricks" or imply by the use of "tricky" that the question, to them, is intentionally made to "trick them."  But if I were you, the better word to use over difficult would be challenging.  Don't use it in a title, but in a post, I see nothing wrong with including something of an introduction: "I'm finding the following integral to be quite challenging for me.  <Post integral>.  <Post your attempts>.  If you hit a road-block, specify why you are stuck, and ask if you are on the right track...etc.

Comment: Solution might be another word to add to the blacklist. Although it might hit some good questions. Idk, I also am not a native speaker.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for being kind and informing..

Comment: @DonThousand  I agree.  The word "tricky" in a title, especially if it reaches the HNQ, is click-bait.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you for not leaving my question unanswered..I tried to get an idea.

Comment: Glad you asked, @lonestudent!

Comment: @amWhy along the same thought process, "answer" might be added to the blacklist. "plz give muh de answerrrrr"

Comment: @DonThousand Asaf has edited the list to include "tricky".  In the comment thread, Asaf said "plz" is blacklisted for titles, meaning no user can use it in any title; the system simply rejects.  But I've seen more than I wish I'd ever seen of titles like: I need an answer NOW!  Or, "I know the answer, but I a step-by-step complete solution."

Comment: @amWhy: The filter is a regex-based pattern match. I think that the goal is not to "cover all options", but rather ensure that the vast majority of bad options are caught. Stragglers can be handled manually.

Comment: One final question, if I can, @Asaf.  I see "Solve/solving", "Simplify,"  Should "Pro[ve|of" be considered?  I think the three most common imperatives used in titles are "Solve, simplify, and "prove" (unfortunately also written as the imperative "proof").  But, I can't say titles with Prove or Proof in them necessarily require filtering.  E.g., A title in which a user asks about "Tarski's proof of Gobble-dee-gook's Theorem: ... "

Comment: @amWhy: I am reluctant to add words like "proof", it has a lot of good and bad results. It's not a "once and done" thing, this filter, so I'd be in favour of starting with just "prove" and not include "proof", and then change it if necessary.

Comment: That works well, @Asaf.  Though I'd love to see a FAQ providing a brief tutorial in English.  Not in any way "to teach English", more covering some basics in mathematical English.  E.g., addressing "When to use "Prove" vs. "Proof".  I wouldn't think of touching question vs. doubt, or "revise vs. review"...  But it might help with tenses/noun/'verbs related to differentiation: "find the derivative of $f(x)", or "differentiate f(x)" (vs. derivate $f(x)$) , similarly integration/integrate/integral...  But I blame you for setting off my brainstorming... this can all be taken up later! :-)

Comment: Every keyword on that list (except possibly "urgent") contains many good questions. It would be very foolish to let software censor math questions shown to the general SE world based on such primitive techniques. This should be done by humans - not by extremely primitive pattern matching (based only on too-broad keywords)

Comment: @Bill: This is not about good questions. It is about good *titles*. The secondary goal is to promote a more proactive editing culture by the core members of the site in a way that includes titles.

Comment: @Asaf  No, it is about **censorship of questions based on primitive keyword matching  of titles** This is probably the most foolish proposal I've encountered in the entire history of the site,

Comment: @Bill: Let's not be overdramatic, yes? We are not talking about blacklisting these questions. Just removing them from the HNQ.

Comment: @Bill  Please read Asaf's post, in particular, read "With that in mind, note that sometimes good questions have bad titles. I still hope that people will push to edit and improve titles of questions just as well as their bodies."  It is not censorship; because there's nothing keeping a post out of HNQ if title is improved. You human reviewers regularly deciding what should stay or what should go on HNQ, then be a human editor to improve titles.  This screen has absolutely nothing to do with banning questions from math.se.

Comment: @Asaf Please remember, **this site is not meant just for us mathematicians**. It's purpose it so serve the **entire (SE) world**. While we may not like some of these elementary questions some of them play a key role in educating the general population.

Comment: @Bill: And if tomorrow the HNQ is cancelled, this goal will no longer be attainable? I'm confused. The default state of a question is *off* the HNQ.

Comment: @Asaf One of the major goals of the HNQ is to expose general-interest topics to a wider audience. Among other things, this may spark students to study mathematics by exposing them to various beautiful elementary topics. Think back to the days of your youth when you encountered various popularizations etc that sparked your interest in math. Without such where would you be now?

Comment: @Bill: Exactly where I am? I got interested in mathematics before the internet came along.

Comment: @Asaf Of course the point was not just about *you*.

Comment: @BillDubuque  this isn't about targeting elementary questions.  Nothing in the word-list filters, out-of-hand, elementary questions.

Comment: @Bill: You asked me where I would have been. I answered that. Let me clarify how it currently works. I check the HNQ list every few hours or so, and remove most, if not all, of what I find there. I explained my process before. The proposed list grew out of this experience. This site has a problem with the HNQ, since MathJax rules out participation there, so questions that get selected often end up to be lower effort, or more specialised and specific topic that are not useful in your imaginary scenario. I am just trying to cut those out of the equation. [...]

Comment: [...] If anything else, this will help the algorithm select *better* questions to the HNQ. So this should be a win-win for everyone, except those people who answer low quality questions, perhaps.

Comment: @Asaf Further, I don't think it is wise to let a *single user* decide which of our  questions should be exposed to the general public - *especially* a user whose specialty (set theory) is perhaps as far removed as can be from fields of mathematics that are more applied.

Comment: In general I think this is a bad idea, but there are a lot of things going on with this site that are bad, and this is not at the top of the list.

Comment: @Asaf Please do explain the reasoning behind your belief that censoring questions containing common English words such as "this, problem, exercise, solve ..."  will  "help the algorithm select better questions to the HNQ". We surely have many thousands of good questions containing those words that would have been mindlessly  censored if we had implemented such a naive filtering strategy.

Comment: @Bill:  Can we please stop using dramatic terms like "censorship"? This is not censorship. Nobody is deleting anything. Nobody is censoring anybody. I know that I'm not a native speaker, but you might want to look up the definition of the term "censorship". It is absolutely impossible to have a mature discussion with someone who from their first post reverts to dramatic tones and extreme imaginary cases. And let's not get into personal attack (what does my specialty have to do with this?)

Comment: @Matt: I'd be happy to hear your thoughts why. You can also post an answer and elaborate, if you feel this is more appropriate.

Comment: @Asaf Your understanding is quite  incorrect (and insulting). So when someone disagrees with your proposal that implies they are " trying to be confrontational"?  What kind of logic is that? Do you want feedback from everyione or only those who agree with you?

Comment: @Bill: No, Matt disagreed without being confrontational. Your first comment started by claiming this is censorship. Once you've climbed on that tree, you refused to come down. I don't know how to help you to do that. This is not censorship. Stop making it sound like we're trying to hide content from the world. While you're at it, it's good to *not* talk about hypothetical. You can look up the questions I've removed from the HNQ (some only after the fact, by the way, when they are closed or edited out), and I am by no means perfect, but many of those are not representatives of high quality.

Comment: @Asaf This question is not about what you have personally removed. Rather it is about what would be removed by the proposed naive keyword filtering. The effects of such most certainly do "hide content from the (SE) world". Whether or not this meets *your* understanding (as a non-native English speaker) of the meaning of "censorship" has little to do with the topic so please stop diverting the discussion with such tangents. Please do explain what you think is "confrontational". I see no such thing.

Comment: @Asaf I don't know why you view in bad light my remark that set-theory is further from applications than some other fields. Most set theorists I know would not argue with that. To clarify my point is this: if there is any hope of making wise decisions on such matters of filtering for nonmath audiences then it is only by including decision makers from as many different fields as possible, Understanding how mathematics interacts with the world is something that does not come easy. The best chance of doing so is when one works in fields that do have close ties with math applications.

Comment: @Bill: Let me just briefly remark, that exactly because set theory is "further away", it forces set theorists to know *more* about general mathematics than people in more "common fields". But yes, I agree that in an ideal situation, we would have a large quorum that decides what goes on the HNQ. Unfortunately, it is an algorithm that picks based on quick answers and high votes. In addition, questions with proper titles tend to be excluded based on MathJax. The result is that most of the picks are decidedly low quality, that were answered by FGIW type of users. This is *how things are*.

Comment: @Asaf I studied set theory, logic and model theory at MIT, so I know well how it interacts with other branches of math.  But I also studied other fields which have much stronger interactions with applications (e.g. abstract algebra). And I also worked on projects that involved close collaboration with leading scientists in many fields (due to my work on Macsyma). This gave me a unique perspective on the diverse applications of math *outside* of pure math. That's not something I can do justice to in a comment. It is astonishing to see all the ingenious ways that math is applied in the world.

Comment: I hope that here we can work to increase these great interdisciplinary applications of math by  using this platform to better expose mathematics. The HNQ list is the primary means of doing such in the SE model. We should strive to use it in the best way possible, not to smother it because some users are angry at cheap rep gained from such questions. That matters very little in the *grand scheme of things*.

Comment: @Bill: I try my best to keep interesting questions from all walks of mathematics on the HNQ, provided their titles do not count as clickbaity. In fact, I am more likely to remove set theory questions (I try to not seem biased, I've already received revenge downvotes for removing questions from the HNQ before). But I will not let you bog this process down with deliberations and committees. HNQ removals are time sensitive.

Comment: @amWhy,Asaf: Plz help!!! Add { "doubt" , "confus(ed?|ion)" , "me" } to the list now. And { "don'?t know" , "what to do" , "my answer( | .* )wrong" }. And { "^(find|solve)" }. =P Also make sure the filter is not case-sensitive.

Comment: @user21820 Asaf states above, in comment responding to "Plz" in the title, when a user tries to include that in the title field, the system rejects it, and until edited, the asker cannot submit it.  "help" is already on the list-in-progress.  I agree that "doubt" should be added to the list, because in many other countries, "I have a doubt..." is equivalent to what we mean when we say "I have a question."  Also, solve is already on the list, but I agree that "[F]ind ... ", as in "Find the next number in the given sequence" or "Find the determinant of the matrix."

Comment: @amWhy: Let me clarify, I said that "plz" *should* be blacklisted, I haven't checked if it is, but if it's not, it will be a bit before this is implemented. In either case, I will work towards that.

Comment: I would prefer if, as well, when a user is writing in the title field, that the software forbids the use of any major tag: Abstract Algebra, Group Theory, Set Theory/Elementary Set Theory, Discrete Math, Logic, Real Analysis, Calculus, etc. etc.  Tags exist for the purpose of identifying the subject matter.  I'm not suggesting these be filter words for HNQ questions, but I am so tired of titles like Linear Algebra (1), Linear Algebra (q1), etc...

Comment: @Asaf I'm sorry I misunderstood you, and misstated what you said.  I agree is should be blacklisted.

Comment: @amWhy: Ah I see I forgot there was a blacklist. Anyway my comment was meant to be some light humour using the dreaded words. =)

Comment: @Asaf Perusing the comments and voting on Theo's [related question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30671/242) six month ago makes it quite clear that there is no strong consensus on these matters. Yet you still wish to impose your very extreme narrow-minded view on the entire community. This is not the way that moderation should work.

Comment: @Bill: I'd call the votes on my answer a pretty reasonable community support. But I'm not planning to spend the rest of the evening arguing with you on abstract definitions again, so let's just call it splitsies and agree that *not acting* is imposing a different kind of view on a different large part of the community which prefers action to inaction.

Comment: @Bill: As I wrote on this page today. If there is such a strong opposition, how come there were no complaints so far? If this has been the status quo for months now, and it hasn't been a secret either, how come no one is complaining? How come people are actively flagging to remove things from the HNQ, and what am I, as a moderator, supposed to do when someone flags? Please, enlighten me.

Comment: But essentially it is a secret - only easily visible to mods. Normal users won't have any clue about such censhorship since they probably don't actively track math HNQ questions. But I have seen comments wondering about why there are very few math questions on the HNQ as of late.

Comment: @Bill: Please, find me these comments. I'm not sure how something that I publicly explained on meta is a secret. People can be involved in this site to the level they wish to be, and if you want to be involved, but don't want to do something about it, then you're not really involved.

Comment: @Asaf But as you said, you've been doing this for a long time. Where did you announce to the community that you would be making such decisions single-handedly?  Was this agreed upon by all members of the mod team?

Comment: @Asaf Currently none of our questions are on the HNQ - which is quite common as of late. This is quite unusual for one of the most active SE sites. Before you were a mod there were frequently a few or more. You are doing a *great disservice* to the mathematiucal world by censoring almost all our HNQ questions.

Comment: @Bill: The moderator team agreed that we'll start by doing it and see how people react or even notice. It took six months for anyone to pay attention, and there were no complaints, and six more months for you to notice that thread and complain. And as I keep repeating, the mod team agreed that there is no need to debate HNQ removals, as these are "time sensitive".

Comment: @Bill: Before I was a moderator the algorithm was also significantly different. And even then, some users (myself included) used to prowl the HNQ and edit the titles of questions that appeared there, if necessary, and thus remove them from the HNQ. (Which prompted some users to actively remove MathJax from titles in attempt to return them to the HNQ, or make them eligible.)

Comment: @Bill: If the algorithm would have been more suitable for this site, I wouldn't have to remove so many questions. Unfortunately, a lot of what it captures is not very good. So a tyrant, rogue moderator ends up removing it. If only we had a filter that captures most of the bad questions, maybe there wouldn't be any need for this tyranny.

Comment: @Asaf You did not answer my question.Again, where was it announced by you (or the mod team) the decision to remove almost all math questions from HNQ?  I find it unbelievable that *all* members of the mod team would support such extreme censorship.

Comment: @Bill: There is no policy to remove "almost all questions". There is a policy to remove questions which are not good advertisements for this site. Want to the HNQ to showcase good questions and good answers. Unfortunately, due to the fact that *most* good questions have MathJax in the title, they are ineligible for HNQ, so the probability of choosing questions which are mediocre or subpar increases. This is the reality of the situation. If you want to change it, spend more time editing more questions to be in better form and have better titles.

Comment: @Asaf When was the last time you allowed an HNQ question to remain on the HNQ list? Please give some recent examples. Better yet, if you have confidence in your decisions then please show us the entire recent history of math HNQ so we can evaluate your decisions. Such powerful and important decisions shouldn't be clouded in secrecy (and they should not be made by a single user).

Comment: @Bill: Several times over the last few days. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3602374/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3599410/ for example. There were a few more, but it would take time to find them, and I have to answer to this angry person on meta right now. So these two will have to suffice. You can use the Data Explorer to find those that weren't removed.

Comment: @Bill: Excuse me if you would feel belittled, but it is known for the last 10 years, that you think that no decision should move forward unless it is 100% unanimous through the entire community, which is very clearly impossible. (I am not going to bring examples from your diamond days, don't worry.) So pardon me when I say, I am not going to take your suggestions seriously unless you come with a better plan that involves compromise and understanding that HNQ questions are a pressing topic that requires immediate response and not weeks of arguing on meta.

Comment: @Asaf I never said any such thing. OTOH, as above, you often try to attack your political opponents by grossly misrepresenting their views.

Comment: @Asaf So in the past week you allowed to stay on HNQ two questions that are so non-elementary that they are likely incomprehensible to most of  the general public. Do you *seriously* think this is good use of the HNQ? This reeks of extreme bias.

Comment: @Bill: And https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598410/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598820/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598545/ are questions that you feel represent high quality content on this website? If so, I invite you to ***please*** edit their titles, at the very least, to show everyone how a creative mind can come up with informative, descriptive, MathJax-free titles.

Comment: @Asaf Are you afraid to show us the *entire* recent history? Powerful decisions like thjs should not be *shrouded in secrecy*.  Obviously by picking and choosing one can distort the truth.

Comment: @Bill: No, I repeatedly sent you off to the Data Explorer. If you don't want to go and do it, please, stop complaining. I will also repeat what I said in that thread from six months ago. I make mistakes, yes. But it seems to me that removing good questions on occasion is not a terrible price for removing most bad questions usually. (And yes, a title is part of the question.)

Comment: @Bill: You can't ask for examples, and then say that I pick and choose the examples. I can't, and I won't, start providing you with justification for the many questions I've removed from the HNQ. Just like I am not going to justify adding MathJax to the titles of HNQ questions since 2012, in order to improve the title and remove them from the list. And now I am going to stop responding to your overly dramatic comments. There is no conspiracy afoot here, and no one is plotting in hidden chambers under the Vatican. Stop assuming that we're all bad faith actors just because we disagree with you.

Comment: @Asaf It is *you* who made this proposal so it is *your* repsonsibility to show the data behind it. That you attempt to shirk this responsibility onto others only lends more credence to the claim you are purposely hiding the data because you know the community will not be pleased seeing the results of your extreme censorship of the HNQ. **Please show us the data.**

Comment: @Bill: I want to clarify in advance. If you see your comments deleted, it's not me. I cannot flag your comments, since my flags are binding, but I may ask one of the other members of the moderator team to curate and delete some of the comments. For now, have a nice evening.

Comment: @asaf I see no reason at all why any comments above should be deleted, do you?

Comment: @Bill: Of course not, you wouldn't make comments that need to be deleted. It's my way of saying, that under normal circumstances, I would have probably flagged a lot of these as unfriendly, or unneeded, or just asked the moderators to clear out parts of this discussion. But being part of the discussion and a moderator, I can't do it directly. But I also know that if you'd see comments missing you'll accuse me of actual censorship. I wanted to clarify in advance, this is not the case.

Comment: @Asaf  So comments that disagree with your political views are "unfriendly, or unneeded"?  In any case it seems clear that you intend to keep your HNQ censorship actions clouded in secrecy so I wont waste any further time arguing for transparency. Alas, it seems that arguments against censorship may be censored too (based on the prior comment).

Comment: @Bill: No. Comments that repeatedly accuse me of being a shadowy puppet master are unfriendly and unkind. As I keep pointing out, it is impossible to hide HNQ removals. It's public data. You are just insisting on being spoon-fed this data. Let me also point out, you don't even need to write the SQL queries, they already exist.

Comment: @asaf Again you are greatly twisting the words of your political opponents. I raised some serious issues of transparency and you twist that into "accusing you of being a shadowy puppet master". That is not a constructive way to discuss such matters. As a mod your actions will be subject to (constructive) critiques (especially when you ask for *more* power but refuse to reveal how you've been using such powers). Handling such critiques is part of the job.

Comment: @Asaf I presumed that the data is much easier to collect using mod tools. But if you know easy ways for normal users to access such HNQ data then please share with us the "SQL queries that already exist". Imo such data should have been included in your question..

Comment: @Bill: I don't think there is any special mod tool for this.

Comment: @Bill: How is me used tools that make it easier to track is being censorship? Would you rather I simply close the low-quality questions and/or edit the titles to include MathJax, and then it's harder to trace what was removed from the HNQ? (I suppose that it also makes it easier to suspend users who undo edits as well, as it is an act of sabotage in quality of questions...) When you do find the queries, by the way, note that some of the results are "false positives", in the sense that I removed them from the HNQ *after* they were disqualified (due to closure or edits).

Comment: @asaf Do you plan to reveal the SQL queries that you alluded to above?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I am motivated by this thread to thank you for the energy and time you put into being a mod here. I don't think I could do it and I appreciate your work.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: I appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Re the recent question on meta, [When I ask a question why review your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31435/when-i-ask-a-question-why-review-your-question), when the asker of a new question hits **Review your question**, will they be warned if their title contains one of the dread words? Or silently allow the question with its dodgy title?

Comment: @Peter: I doubt that there will be a warning. If it is up to me, I would be happy to forbid some of these words altogether. But the point is help the algorithm filter out questions and have a better chance of finding questions which we want to represent the site on the SE network. Good questions *should* have good, informative titles.

Comment: I humbly ask the the Bill-Asaf debate be moved to, or at least continued, in a chatroom.

Comment: @amWhy: I'd be happy with that (not the continuation, we're at an impasse at the moment anyway; but the removal). But that puts Bill at a disadvantage, as it means that he can no longer delete his comments anymore. If he is okay with that, I'm fine with having those comments moved (by a third party moderator anyway).

Comment: I see that SEDE query showing the removals of post from the HNQ list was asked in some of the comments above. I have posted such query in comments to [the previous discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/under-what-criteria-should-we-remove-questions-from-the-hnq-list#comment132956_30671), in any case, here it is once again: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1013246/questions-removed-from-hnq-by-mods?num=500

Comment: @Martin You also need  [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1149151/hnq-hits) in order to confirm that the prior list of mod-removed questions constitutes almost *all* of our HNQ questions, i.e few if any were allowed to remain on the hot list (for quite some time). Essentially we have no more hot list. We now reside in an (opaque) walled garden in the SE community. Alas, transparency is greatly lacking here nowadays - in many faceted ways.

Comment: @Asaf I can't make any sense of your prior comment about "deleting comments". I don't recall deleting any comments on this page.

Comment: @Bill: First of all, you did delete a couple of comments in the process of revising them, just to remind you of this (this was below Theo's answer), but I did not claim that you did any of that. Secondly, you *can* delete your comments now, but if we move the discussion to a chatroom, you won't have that ability. It puts you at a disadvantage, and I rather not be in charge of that. But as circular discussion reached its inevitable conclusion, let's just cut here. We are getting wildly off topic.

Comment: What's/ who's CMs?

Comment: @MagicConchShell: Community Managers. The Stack Exchange employees that oversee the various communities.

Comment: @asaf  As a mod, you can see that I didn't do anything fishy around comment deletion  (fixing typos is not fishy). So I would appreciate it if you you refrained from making comments that could easily be misconstrued otherwise. And you shouldn't be revealing mod-private info anyways (even when its harmless) since that violates mod terms. All the more so in delicate contexts as this when conversing with a user who is seriously questioning some of your mod actions.

Comment: @BillDubuque ah I see what you mean, you completely changed them within the 5 minute time _but_ didn't delete, right?

Comment: @MagicConchShell  I don't recall every typo I've fixed (does anyone?). But my prior comment is an example. The 5 minute edit timer ran out while editing it so I had to delete and repost it to fix the typos etc. Likely that's what I did in the other 2 cases Asaf refers to but I don't recall (they were long ago). I make a lot of typos these days since I am testing different input devices to work around RSI injuries.

Comment: @BillDubuque I understand your point, it's fine. Hope you get better in the working around the RSI injuries 

Comment: @Magic If only it were that easy. Meta has had a longstanding problem with political battles fought unscrupulously using ad hominem attacks, twisting the words of others etc. We need to nip these problems in the bud if we are to have any hope of having constructive rational discussions - so that we can devise good compromises on contentious matters. In particular, meta has to be moderated in a way that *everyone* feels comfortable enough to share their views (including unpopular views) without fear of being viciously attacked. This is *essential* to the success of meta (and main).

Comment: @BillDubuque I have posted a few additional queries [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97476/conversation/hnq-and-their-removals). If further queries are needed (or some improvements to the existing ones), it can be discussed there.

Comment: Please consider voting my answer as you see fit so that we can understand whether the community is for/against this proposal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, why "simplify" is included in the list?

Comment: @CulverKwan: The goal is not to remove elementary questions. If a title contains the word "simplify" and is uninformative, it is very likely to also have some other words (e.g. "this" or "the following").

Comment: I don't know why some people seem to be trusting some BS biased algorithm more than Asaf.

Comment: @Paul: I also *really* don't know. I understand that I am somewhat extreme. And people are probably more receptive to the HNQ than I am. But I was taken aback by how far the disagreement goes. I'm fine being called a censor and a dictator, it's part of the job. But a lot of the discussion here makes no sense to me from a rational point of view...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This request is, specifically, declined but we have added a subset of words to the HNQ filter just now.

Using the responses to the question asked by quid: [Which words (if any) in the title of a question should prevent inclusion in the HNQ list?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/which-words-if-any-in-the-title-of-a-question-should-prevent-inclusion-in-the) I've requested the top upvoted answers there to be added to the HNQ block and I've marked those words [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

The filter regex looks like this:

`(\W|^)(?i)(urgent|ASAP|please|pls|help)(\W|$)`

Some things to note

- Unlike a moderator removal, editing the title will make a question eligible for the HNQ list the next time it compiles.
- Based on the [excellent analysis by Ilmari Karonen](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31554/245649), I'm not sure how impactful the filters we did add will be. There don't seem to be any super common words in titles that indicate problems.

Neither of these things are particularly surprising. The first is by design and the second... is designed less to prevent low-quality content getting in - which is what y'all are trying to do - and more to prevent abusive or offensive content from getting in.

If y'all have thoughts on better ways we could help address this issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 15):

For what it's worth, I took the SEDE query [posted earlier in the comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/138245) and tweaked it to [generate some statistics](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1229712/monthly-stats-on-hnq-hits-with-proposed-autofilters) on the historical effectiveness of the proposed autofilter.

Specifically, my query returns a monthly count of:

- the total number of questions selected for HNQ in that month,
- the number of those questions that were either closed or manually removed from HNQ by a moderator, and
- both of the above, but limited only to questions whose title (at the time they were picked for HNQ) would pass the proposed autofilter.

Anyway, [looking at the results](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1229712/monthly-stats-on-hnq-hits-with-proposed-autofilters#graph), I'm not too hopeful about the effectiveness of this proposed filter in keeping bad questions out of HNQ:

[image: Graph]

As you can see from the graph, the autofilter only matches about 10% of all HNQs on math.SE.  Furthermore, it appears to be matching roughly the same fraction of both good and bad questions (or, at least, of questions that were and weren't closed or manually removed from HNQ in the past).

In other words, at least based on this historical data, the proposed filter — regardless of its other merits, or lack thereof — would appear to have no significant effect on the fraction of HNQs that are closed or manually removed.

(Of course, the query can't tell us what other questions might have been selected to replace the 10% that would've been filtered out, had the autofilter been in place when they were hot.  However, it seems reasonable to assume that those questions would not have been statistically too dissimilar from the ones that were actually selected.)

---

Ps. If you'd like to examine the underlying data in more detail, [here's a version of the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1229695/hnq-hits-with-proposed-autofilters) that returns the raw list of past HNQs and whether or not they match the filter.

---

Pps. Here's [a version of the query the returns percentage statistics](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1229773/percentage-stats-for-hnq-hits-with-proposed-autofilters#graph) on the fraction of questions closed or removed from HNQ among those that either pass or match the proposed autofilter:

[image: Graph]

Of course, there's no actual new data here — you could easily generate these percentages just by dropping the raw question counts from the first query above into a spreadsheet — but this might provide a useful alternative visualization.

As this graph shows, the questions that match the proposed filter aren't historically any more likely to get closed or removed from HNQ than those that don't, at least not until the last couple of months.  Since February 2020, questions matching the filter do seem to get removed from HNQ a bit more often than those that don't, but this could be just a statistical coincidence.  (It also seems to correlate with an uptick in the number of questions removed from HNQ in general.)

Even within the last few months, however, automatically applying the autofilter would not have made much difference to the overall removal rate: the yellow and blue lines track each other very closely over the whole period for which data is available.  At best, in March 2020, having the autofilter in place would've reduced the manual HNQ removal rate from 87% to 85%.

(Again, this is assuming that the questions that pass the filter and did get selected as HNQs are also statistically representative of the questions that would've been picked to replace the ones filtered out, which cannot be proven but seems like a reasonable assumption.)

---

Ppps. Just for the sake of curiosity, prompted by [Paul Plummer's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/139332) below, I did a little bit of exploratory data analysis using the data from the [detailed query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1229695/hnq-hits-with-proposed-autofilters) above.  In particular, I tried looking for words* that have occurred *only* in the titles of removed (or closed) HNQs, and which have occurred in more than two such titles.  Here they are, grouped by the number of such titles they occur in:

- 7: delta
- 5: h, l, students, let
- 4: rolls, whole, distributing, separable, extended, trace, start, reciprocal, letter, hold
- 3: finish, proposition, require, i'm, seeking, negation, morphism, add, puzzle, cut, entries, direction, associative, roll, symmetry, eight, variation, symbol, moves, average, english, squeeze, clear, cancellation, uncountably, hypothesis, physics, towards

So, what does that list tell us?  I'd say not much, except that it's kind of hard to reliably detect bad HNQs using word filters.

Would we want to add an autofilter for "delta"?  Maybe.  Doing so would've saved us from a whole seven (presumably) low-quality HNQs over the past year or so.  Adding in "let" and "students" would increase that to 17, assuming that none of those three words have occurred in the same title (which I haven't checked).

On the other hand, I'd assume we probably don't want to autofilter "separable", "extended" or "trace" (or the letters "h" and "l"), even though statistically those all seem to be better indicators for bad HNQs than any of the proposed filter keywords above.

<sup>*) For the purposes of this exploratory study, I'm defining a word as a sequence of the letters A–Z, digits 0–9 and apostrophes.  All titles were converted to lower case before analysis.</sup>

---

FWIW, I also looked at which words would appear to be the best overall predictors of a HNQ getting removed or closed, using add-one [additive smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing) to discount infrequently occurring words.  (In other words, I ranked the words based on the score $(1 + n_b) \mathbin/ (2 + n_b + n_g)$, where $n_b$ and $n_g$ are the number of "bad" and "good" titles the word occurs in.)  Here are all the words with score > 0.75:

- delta: 0.89 (7 bad, 0 good)
- h, l, students, let: 0.86 (5 bad, 0 good)
- rolls, whole, distributing, separable, extended, trace, start, reciprocal, letter, hold: 0.83 (4 bad, 0 good)
- expectation, properties, 20: 0.82 (8 bad, 1 good)
- finish, proposition, require, i'm, seeking, negation, morphism, add, puzzle, cut, entries, direction, associative, roll, symmetry, eight, variation, symbol, moves, average, english, squeeze, clear, cancellation, uncountably, hypothesis, physics, towards: 0.8 (3 bad, 0 good)
- verify, column, school: 0.78 (6 bad, 1 good)

<sup>(The reason for setting the cutoff at > 0.75 is that after that comes a long list of words that each appear in exactly two "bad" HNQ titles and no "good" titles.  Most of those look even more like just random coincidences than the words already listed above.)</sup>

Not too surprisingly, this looks very similar to the previous list.  The only difference is the addition of the words "expectation", "properties", "verify", "column", "school" and the number "20", all of which appear in the titles of sufficiently many HNQs that were removed or closed to counterbalance their appearance in the title of one HNQ that wasn't as well.

FWIW, trying add-*two* additive smoothing instead (to favor common words over rare ones even more) still gives the same old list of usual suspects as before, but also brings up a few more words that occur notably more often in the titles of HNQs that get removed or closed than of those that don't, such as "true" (17 bad, 5 good), "countable" (14 bad, 4 good), "contains" (8 bad, 2 good), "three" (22 bad, 8 good), "up" (10 bad, 3 good) and "determinant" (19 bad, 7 good), as well as "maximal", "rotation", "gives", "epsilon", "black" and "sine" (5 bad, 1 good each).

I'll leave it up to the reader to decide whether any of those words would actually make good autofilter entries.

Comment: It should be added that if a question is filtered out, another one takes its place.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks, noted.

Comment: Also, I think one of the queries mentioned in other threads and by Martin on the chat show how many questions were removed from the HNQ by adding MathJax to the title, so I suppose that you can in fact test to see what was the title at the time of the HNQ status being given, as well as the title once the question was removed or closed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: *Any* questions that were selected for HNQ, but now have MathJax in the title, clearly were edited at some point (and would've been removed from HNQ by the edit, if they were still there when edited). That much is easy to tell. I just edited the "raw" query to include (and mark) those questions, and I could easily add a count of them to the stats query, but I don't see what insight that would give on the effectiveness of the proposed filter. Actually pulling the old titles from the edit history, on the other hand, is possible but awkward. I'm too tired to even try it right now.

Comment: If a question is "This limit is hard", and it is edited to "How do I prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}x=0$?", then the original title would be caught by the filter, whereas the edited title is removed by MathJax.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I went and implemented the edit history digging after all. The updated graphs above are now based on the original title at the time the question was picked for HNQ. The differences appear to be minimal — if anything, looking at the original titles seems to make the performance of the autofilter look slightly worse.

Comment: What I truly wonder is whether or not this means that the idea of an autofilter is silly, or that the community's response is exaggerated.

Comment: Very cool. Not saying you should do this, but maybe data people would be interested in this: are there commonalities in the titles of removed questions which are far less likely to occure in questions which are never removed?(and maybe we should take into account some "false positive/negative statistics" to decide whether or not it is worth it)

Comment: I suspect that there probably isn't anything to meaningful, maybe if expanded to phrases, or someone did some crazy machine learning which was fed "bad questions" and "good questions." Would the machine be able to tell the difference?

Comment: @PaulPlummer: See edit above. TBH, my personal conclusion is that single-word filters, at least, are not very good at telling bad HNQs from good ones. Maybe something like a (naïve) Bayesian classifier that considered _all_ the words in the title together could do better; but unfortunately all we have is a regexp filter.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen This is a very insightful and well-written analysis, the kind of objective thing that is needed in contentious issues. Thanks for taking your time to do this.

Answer (score 9):

I haven't logged into this site for some time, but I felt I needed to to register my displeasure if our community indeed marches further down this route. This might not come as a surprise, given my last meta question: [Under what criteria should we remove questions from the HNQ list?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/under-what-criteria-should-we-remove-questions-from-the-hnq-list)

> Let me start by stating that the goal is to filter out bad titles. If it happens that some good questions get filtered out, it is unfortunate, but the default state of a question is off the HNQ, and the current consensus of the moderators is that it is more important to keep questions which we do not want to represent our site off this list.

I wholeheartedly disagree with the conclusion here, as well as the reasoning leading to it. The default state of a question is not necessarily on or off the HNQ, and liable to be placed on the HNQ list should whatever algorithms in place decide that it should be there. The moderators (typically Asaf, but others as well) have taken a heavily interventionalist approach to removing questions from the HNQ list, which strikes me as the opposite of the "natural state".

In the actual natural state, we see the questions that our readers wish to see are promoted visibly, bringing people to our site, and promoting mathematics in the community. It gives people in the network of sites, including people who don't frequent MSE, an opportunity to see digestible nuggets of mathematics that's of interest to them.

Clearly, this will bias towards the elementary questions. I understand that we might see fewer, original, deep questions with meaty, informative answers in the HNQ if we have a flood of elementary questions in the HNQ. But, and let me highlight this, **having questions on the HNQ is not to benefit our regular contributors**.

We have bounties for this; if you think a question is particularly interesting, or has a particularly nice answer that you wish others to see, you can leave a bounty on the question and/or answer. This will bump the question to the list of [bountied questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=bounties) for enthusiasts to peruse.

I still think we should leave the HNQ alone, in a vast majority of situations. None of us have to actually like the questions on there, since we are not the target audience. It feels like our moderation team is attempting to reduce our site's relevance to the community.

---

So, as you'd imagine, I'm fairly against this proposal of blacklisting certain words, and some of these words more than others. Some words, like "solve" and (to a lesser extent) "simplify", strike me as extremely prejudicial. There are plenty of extremely interesting equations and algebraic expressions that can make for interesting questions.

It also heavily biases against elementary questions, which frequently involve "solving" and "simplifying". This smacks of that icky feeling that we are profiling people, not questions. It feels like we are implicitly taking the position that certain levels of maths are too basic to be sufficiently interesting (a certain [comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/under-what-criteria-should-we-remove-questions-from-the-hnq-list#comment132991_30673) on my previous question springs to mind).

I understand that we don't wish to publicise the questions we don't want on MSE, but I just don't think that the HNQ questions are any significant causal agent here. Just look at the number of new contributors, asking low quality questions, with less than 15 reputation. I don't think that any of them read the guidelines, thought that they shouldn't post their question as it was, then saw a low quality HNQ and decided that it was actually fine. I just don't think that happens. I'm just not sure what we're getting in exchange for all the babies we're prepared to flush with the bath water.

If we do implement such a blacklist, I think we should restrict ourselves to things like "plz", "urgent", "help", and other things that shouldn't be in the title of any question, and can be edited out/replaced without damaging the question. This way, it doesn't feel like we are censoring content and dictating what people should be interested in, merely helping ensure that whatever is published on the HNQ is well-presented.

I know that this opinion is somewhat unpopular in a certain sector of MSE, and unfortunately, this sector of MSE encompasses all the moderators, but I needed to say my piece.

Comment: I think that having done this for a while, I can very clearly tell you that some people *do* benefit from the question they answer being on the HNQ. And that we already saw example of people purposefully making titles bad just to get to the HNQ list, and that I see a significant number of questions closed or with 3+ votes to close, by the time I remove them from the HNQ. I *want* the HNQ to promote *good* content. Low quality content is *not* good content. Bad titles are *not* good content.

Comment: The word "this" shouldn't appear in almost all cases of titles that I've seen it appear in. "Solve this integral" should be "How do I compute $\int e^x\ dx$", or "Solve this limit without L'Hospital" should be "How do I compute $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{x^2}$ without using L'Hospital?". And yes, this *is* the prevalent majority of questions that end up with "this" on the HNQ.

Comment: "I want the HNQ to promote good content. Low quality content is not good content. Bad titles are not good content." But "good" is a subjective term. Again, it sounds like you're trying to get the HNQ to function like an automated bounty system, rejecting things you don't personally find interesting, and promoting things you do. If you want to promote good content, why not put a bounty on some good questions instead? It's not like you can't spare the reputation. I don't accept the axiom that we, as power users, have to like the questions on the HNQ. So, why is it important that we prune it so?

Comment: Theo, I am not trying to promote things I find interesting. I am trying to promote well-written questions with well-written answers. And I am trying to minimise the gamification aspect of answering quickly low-quality questions that have bad titles. Because yes, there is gamification, and we see it in action. And yes, it is toxic to this website.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Toxic in what respect?

Comment: I think "we see the questions that our readers wish to see are promoted visibly" is not really to the point. We see the questions that an algorithm selects based on actions taken by users collectively *and* mostly for a different purpose. That's *really* not the same thing.

Comment: Really? Okay. Well, when people only play for points, there is a race to get more points. This means that good content is ignored in favour of bad content that can provide quicker dopamine kick. If the goal is to promote the idea that mathematics is interesting, then showcasing a bunch of "How to solve the following integral" is not the way to do that, except in *very specific cases*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So, am I right in thinking that you believe that people who would otherwise post questions the mods would personally find interesting would instead invest their energy into getting rep points via gaming the HNQ, and that's why it's toxic? I'm trying to find a reason that isn't based on trying to profile people, and pre-excluding them from this site and mathematics in general, because I personally find that kind of attitude abhorrent.

Comment: @quid I think it's approximately the same thing, and it's a helluva lot closer to this than the system currently in place. I've seen plenty of perfectly adequate, lower level questions, be removed quickly from the HNQ. I can see the bias of the current system at work, and it seems heavily biased against the people at whom HNQs are actually aimed.

Comment: No. You're now reducing my words to a fallacy, and then claiming it's "abhorrent". This is *not* what I think, and this is *not* the reality. The reality is that there are a number of users here which are using this platform as a fun website to answer questions. They don't care where the questions come from, or whether or not they have any long-standing value. This was acceptable when the site was small, but it's not a small site anymore. What we are trying to do is preserve the difference between this site and Yahoo! Answers, at least for a little while longer.

Comment: @TheoBendit do you know how the algorithm works?

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, you misread my comment; I'm trying to find the interpretation that's not abhorrent. You seem to be concerned that somehow the gamification is going to reduce quality content. I don't see how that works. You keep replying to me as though I share these convictions you have that gamification has to be stopped wherever possible. So, I'm forced to try to fill in the holes in your arguments. I really don't mean to misrepresent you; I'm just trying to understand your position.

Comment: @quid I don't, actually. From what I've seen from my own excursion to other sites, it's done a fairly good job thusfar of offering interesting tidbits from other sites to me.

Comment: The point about gamification is that it is predicated on hooking into your reward system. So you no longer do things "because it's good", but rather "because it feels good". We saw users ravage through bad edits, just to get certain badges, or go on voting sprees just to get badges; and other users actively lowering quality of questions just to have them on HNQ; or users answering every low-quality precalculus question they can find, just to get more votes. Yes, each of those single incidents is innocent, but when you step back, you start seeing a bigger picture. And it's not a very good one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila OK, so trying to edit questions, in a way that makes them worse, in order to get on the HNQ, I will agree that this is bad behaviour caused by the HNQ. The other stuff seems tangential, and not really related to the HNQ directly. I'm just wondering, is it not better to simply roll back the edits, and possibly talking to the user about damaging their own posts? Constantly removing questions seems like a band-aid solution, and this blacklist (particularly the words I highlighted) seems like the amputation option. Why bias the HNQ through crude technological measures?

Comment: I explained gamification, because you said you're not sure how that makes the site worse. The fact that a lot of bad questions end up on HNQ, and thus are more likely to reward "myopic actors" (they are not necessarily bad actors, they just treat each question separately, and don't care about its origin, or what is the bigger effect on this site being view as a "human-powered Wolfram|Alpha"). To your last question, the HNQ *is* a crude technological tool. If it was a refined one, we would have opted for a refined approach.

Comment: My view here, by the way, is also motivated by the quest for informative titles. And I don't see why questions with *bad titles* should be promoted network-wide. "Solve my problem" is a terrible title, why do you want it on the HNQ?

Comment: @AsafKaragila OK, so I think I'm starting to get it. **This is my best guess; please correct me if I'm wrong.** You want to do this thing to to the HNQ, not to get interesting questions into it, but to remove some of the incentive to post low quality questions, or to damage one's own posts in favour making it onto the HNQ?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's not about wanting the title "Solve my problem", it's about not wanting to automatically exclude titles along the lines of "How could we solve ______?" The title can be perfectly informative in that syntax, and questions with that title are not necessarily uninteresting

Comment: No, it is *both* to encourage people to answer good questions, and even edit low-quality ones. But also I want this because if the algorithm knows to ignore bad questions, it is more likely to choose *good* ones instead.

Comment: Theo, can you give me five examples of an informative titles that use the word "this"? (I agree, "problem" is a borderline one.) Can you give me *any* title that contains "advice" that is not actively off-topic on this site in March 2020?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure, I haven't looked. Off the top of my head? Certainly not. I'm fairly sure I've seen the word "advice" in a title of an on-topic book recommendation at least once. As you said in the original post, you accept that not every automatically excluded question will be bad, so I'm not going to bother challenging you on it, but that's a significant part of what is bothering me about this.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was confused by your [comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31425/autofilters-for-hot-network-questions/31431#comment138074_31431); I thought it wasn't about promoting what is interesting. Now that I'm clearer on this, it does again feel like you are projecting your own tastes onto both the HNQ and the site in general. I feel more comfortable with you doing that with the site as the whole (you are an elected moderator, after all), but I feel less comfortable regarding the HNQ, because again, it's not really for you. It's OK if it's not to your tastes.

Comment: If you don't know how it work, then I cannot see how you can assert what you have asserted. What may be true is that you empirically observe that the algorithm selects things that you think actually should be on the HNQ, but that's again something else.

Comment: Theo, I have to leave for a bit, but let me comment shortly about "my taste of things". It is not about that. The only *complaints* I got about my aggressive HNQ filtering so far is a few downvotes. On the other hand, I actively see other people edit titles to include MathJax or flag to have questions removed. I also don't see why "the automated guess of someone who is not a member of this community" should be taken as holy, whereas input from the community on the results of this algorithm is less important.

Comment: @quid Well no, that's more or less what I've said. I've observed that the HNQ has been successful in drawing me into other sites, broadening my horizons. I'd like the reciprocal force to pull others into mathematics, even if it's only temporary. I've observed that the HNQ does this for me, and I've assumed I'm not special in any way, so I think it'll happen for plenty of other people too. I certainly admit, I haven't done the studies or the statistics, so feel free to share your data.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "Theo, I have to leave for a bit, but let me comment shortly about 'my taste of things'. It is not about that." I just don't think it's true though. You've talked about your disgust over gamification as justification, as well as now a desire to clear what is "bad" in favour of what is "good". As I said before, it's clearly more than just site guidelines. These are all subjective judgements, informed by your own tastes in questions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "The only complaints I got about my aggressive HNQ filtering so far is a few downvotes. On the other hand, I actively see other people edit titles to include MathJax or flag to have questions removed." The people that the HNQ is aimed at are not common participants in the site, and therefore extremely unlikely to be involved in Meta MSE, or to even have a well-formed opinion about which sites should or should not be on the HNQ. I think your observations, while true, aren't actually all that relevant.

Comment: Possibly there is some confusion regarding the scope of "readers" in the sentence I quoted in my first comment. There is likely a discussion to be had what the purpose of the HNQ is. I agree that the what is interesting for me or you or  Asaf personally is not a relevant criterion. However, I see the HNQ as a way to promote the site to others. Therefore I think that we should control the content so as to be in line with the way we want the site, and its subject, to be seen. The main goal is not provide fun reading material for whoever.

Comment: @quid I do respect this opinion, even if I do mostly disagree with the last two sentences. I think fun is actually really important, and something that people perceive is missing in maths. I was happy enough (sort of) with the arrangement before, even though I really do think it biases against the core audience of the HNQ, but it was a fine enough compromise. I really dislike this idea of blacklisting common words, especially if it means effectively blacklisiting entire classes of elementary questions.

Comment: Theo, now I'm confused about the comment of mine you linked. I said, which is the same thing I keep saying. This is not about what I find interesting, I would be happy to leave all set theory questions on the HNQ, and kick out all the rest, but I don't do that. I leave questions that read to me as genuine and interesting questions, broad or specialised, that have good and interesting answers. The goal is to help the algorithm reduce noise ***and*** to help reduce gamification concerns. (You still haven't given me those examples I was asking for.)

Comment: Ultimately, what we have here, is the same thing we do in every policy discussion. People take an imagined scenario, and they think this is the common one. And I agree, we shouldn't exclude questions just because they are elementary or simple. But the reality is that those also tend to be of very low quality, and attract answers which are not always of the best quality either. I am not talking about some hypothetical-land where the algorithm "works in our favour", but rather about my experience in the last few months with the algorithm and its choices.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not going to reply again about the examples. Read my comment, then read the penultimate paragraph from my answer. You don't fill the HNQ with set theory, that's true, but you still make judgements about what people should see and find interesting on the site. It doesn't have to pique your research-based interests, but it does seem to have to meet your criteria about being "good", which as I've pointed out, is a standard above and beyond the standards of the site, as judged by you and your fellow mods.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "But the reality is that those also tend to be of very low quality, and attract answers which are not always of the best quality either." I'm glad to hear you say that. I would prefer, in general, that we improve the quality of these questions, rather than removing them. Failing that, I would **very much** prefer that we don't automatically exclude questions that involve solving an equation!

Comment: So you want to penalise (yes, penalise) users who took the time to write a title "How do I simply $x^4-y=4x+z$", because they wrote an informative title that contained MathJax and thus are *automatically* become ineligible to be on the HNQ (i.e. the default status now is *off* the list), and reward users who simply wrote "Help me solve this equation" because they got two answers that were voted by a core group of users? Yes, that will definitely work to let people on the SE network see mathematics as more than solving equations.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would rather change "Help me solve this equation" to a more informative title, and if it stays in the HNQ, then good for it. The consequences of this blacklist are, to me, more chilling.

Comment: Yes, and you can't change it to an informative title that doesn't involve any of the words "Please help solve this"? Note that "equation" is not suggested as a blacklist word, not by me, nor by anyone in the comments.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If I it's one of the uncommon cases where a more informative title cannot be thought of, then I'd be in favour of letting it slide. It's not a big deal. And while equation is not blacklisted, "solve" and "simplify" currently are.  These are probably the biggest verbs in elementary mathematics, and even when an equation is not involved, low-level students will use "solve" more generally (e.g. "How do I solve this proof?"). Blocking these does not mean blocking poorly-worded titles, it means blocking elementary students and their questions. That's not right, and it damages the HNQ.

Comment: It damages the HNQ? In what sense? That it prevents low quality, uninformative, and ambiguous titles from being there?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It partially prevents the HNQ from fulfilling its purpose: for our site to reach out to the wider community, and pull in other people through questions and answers they find interesting. As we bias away from what attracts people, and towards the less elementary and more esoteric questions, we alienate these people. If you really wanted to prevent low quality, uninformative, and ambiguous titles in the HNQ, we could always set our number of questions to 0. Sure we'd lose some good questions, but the important thing is, we don't encourage gamification...

Comment: Yes, when they asked us initially for what we want to put in the filter, I jokingly said "*", knowing that it might had been considered a bit extreme. Instead, I decided to spend a few months following the trends of what gets on the HNQ, and then make a more informed decision. Hence my current list.

Comment: @AsafKaragila We seem to have come to a halt. I've explained/defended my position to my satisfaction, and I'm getting sleepy. I may or may not come back tomorrow.

Comment: Theo, that is fine with me. Let me point out, again, that your position seems to me as somehow naive, and ignoring what is happening in reality with what questions make it to the HNQ, and how the algorithm works (other than "on other sites it works fine"). As well as what it means to have an informative title. Of course, this is a matter of opinion, as a whole, and you're entitled to your opinion.

Comment: @Theo I may have missed the point I am about to make, if it was already made in this thread.  I see the HNQ as reflection to other users of what our site is about.  Historically, the questions chosen by the algorithms have favored showing poor posts, because it can't even include mathjax.  This is my point: I also see the HNQ as exhibiting what many others on the SE network think "must be okay because, heck, it's on the HNQ", some are, more are not.  So if they then decide to come check us out, at math.se, they're impression of "what's welcome" on this site may in fact be erroneous.

Comment: ...In this way, those newcomers may be greatly disadvantaged and confused if their very poor posts or problem statements get downvoted and closed.

Comment: @AmWhy I'm sure that plenty of PSQs do make it onto the HNQ list, and while I don't see them much, I guess that's because mods remove them. However, I doubt that the HNQ has much, if any, influence on the behaviour of users (outside of what's mentioned [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31425/autofilters-for-hot-network-questions/31431#comment138090_31431)). Most of the regular users on Stack Exchange sites know that the sites have their own standards, and the HNQ is not a badge of approval. I also think most of our problematic new recruits just don't bother reading anything.

Comment: @TheoBendit You think that it is beneficial for the HNQ to have more elementary questions in order to draw attention from people that are *not* "us", correct? If that is so, wouldn't it be best that the merits of that attention reside in the content and that content alone, whatever it is? Think about, say, articles on the internet that say "Hey, here are some unknown facts about potatoes! You won't believe number 9!". We want to avoid those things, encouraging instead things like "Here are some facts about potatoes and their health benefits." The content is invariant.

Comment: Re: "Clearly, this will bias towards the elementary questions. I understand that we might see fewer, original, deep questions with meaty, informative answers in the HNQ if we have a flood of elementary questions in the HNQ." This line of thought would apply if there were ideas of filtering HNQ questions by tags instead of titles, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @Aloizio Could you please provide some feedback on the accuracy of [the claim](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31425/autofilters-for-hot-network-questions#comment138155_31425) that "The moderator team agreed that we'll start by doing it and see how people react or even notice". In particular, is the mod team aware that almost all questions have been removed from the HNQ for quite some time, all by Asaf alone? Do they condone this extreme censorship? If so, where was that decision announced to the community?

Comment: Does the moderator team frequently make such secret policy decisions then wait to "see how people react or even notice"? Probably this deserves a separate meta question but it would be helpful to get some feedback first for context.

Comment: @quid Please see the above two comments. In particular, could you please clarify which members of the mod team agreed to support this secret policy.

Comment: @BillDubuque the paraphrase seems accurate to me. It's been about a year though. Certainly the entire team's input was solicited. Likely not everybody expressed a view (as you no doubt noted several mods are hardly active) but I would not recall any relevant dissent; there was some discussion and active support for managing the list actively and I am aware how it is done.

Comment: @quid Does that imply that you supported this decision?  And that you agreed that it was ok not to notify the community about this secret policy decision but rather to "start by doing it and see how people react or even notice"? Are you also aware that Asaf has been removing almost *all* of the HNQ questions. Do you seriously believe that the community would support such extreme censorship, and such secret policy making decisions?

Comment: @BillDubuque You use the term "secret" multiple times. That moderators could do this was linked in the Math Meta chat (where it should be): https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/64952/2019/3/11 , and then commented about in subsequent days by Martin. If you want to criticize, perhaps a more accurate word could be *intransparent*. That critique might have more ground, but we agreed at the time that it wasn't something controversial and that by drawing (more) attention about these things there was a high probability of conflation with the reopen/close issues, which is a distinct phenomenon.

Comment: @Aloizio Please clarify why you believe that the link you posted has anything to do with the topic at hand. Is the mod team in the habit of also secretly making policy decisions by "agreeing that it wasn't something controversial"? The more I hear the more my jaw drops...

Comment: @BillDubuque "But essentially it is a secret - only easily visible to mods. Normal users won't have any clue about such censhorship[sic] since they probably don't actively track math HNQ questions." From this comment I infer that you think such a "censorship" was a secret. It wasn't, as my link shows.

Comment: @Aloizio That link has nothing to do with the issues I raised. Why do you believe otherwise?

Comment: @Alozio Btw, if you read your linked post carefully you will see that SE team wrote  the following about the then newly introduced feature of moderator-manual-removal of HNQ questions "**This tool is a big gun and should be used sparingly**". Does Asaf's longtime manual removal of almost *all* of our HNQ questions count as "sparingly"?

Comment: Clearly such extreme (ab)use of this moderator power was not intended by the SE team. It thwarts the basic design of the system by completely smothering external dissemination of knowledge. Not to mention the extreme bias imposed by having a *single* member of the community make these very powerful decisions about what content is worthy of exposing to the general (SE) public.

Comment: @BillDubuque Those are more sensible critiques. (Albeit still imbued with some unneeded ornamentations imo.) However, as far as the post goes, it seems to me that the suggestion addresses precisely what you claim to be problematic, since the process would be more automatic, driven by community feedback and less in the hands of one person. If you wish to complain about Asaf's removals, this post seems to be the opposite place to do so. Perhaps [the post mentioned by Theo](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/) makes more sense for that.

Comment: @Bill: Let me point out that you were fully aware of that post by Theo. You left a comment there over a month *after* I had posted my answer. That means that you had all the necessary information back then. So I am not quite certain why you're all riled up.

Comment: @Asaf Non sequitur inference. That you are responsible for 98% of *mod-removed* questions implies nothing at all about the total percentage of mod-removed questions. It could be some very small number (as SE recommends). But in fact it is very large - almost all of them. I don't recall knowing that then (I'm sure if I did then I would have strongly objected just as I did here).

Comment: @BillDubuque yes I supported the decision. I would not personally remove that many questions but I don't mind either. I think most users would not either. Basically hardly anyone really cares, it's a non-issue except if one wants to make a point of it in which case a discussion without any conclusion will ensue. This is why I was also in favor of not starting it back then. Further,,it was a longstanding informal practice to kick questions from HNQ via the MathJax hack. Nothing is new. Also SE is of course aware that mathematics kicks a lot as they diligently track adoption of added features.

Comment: @quid Of course people can't object to things that have been purposely hidden from their view. Moderators shouldn't be implementing secret policies based on wild guesses that "most users would not care". This is not how we ran the site in the past and it is not how it should be run now. Rather, we actively solicited community input on all such policies. I have lost all faith in the current mod team due to this major abuse of mod powers. In my opinion anyone who supported this extreme censorship should resign and apologize to the community.

Comment: @BillDubuque the past was full of pointless discussions and gridlock. We learned from it and thus did not repeat it.

Comment: @quid Seriously? You think that because there is a diversity of opinion on these fundamental matters that gives you the right to go devise your own secret policies and then wait to "see how people react or even notice"? You think that is ok to greatly abuse moderators powers that SE explicitly says are "big guns and should be used sparingly" by using them to remove every HNQ question, thus preventing those in other  fields from benefiting from the knowledge on this site?  I cannot believe what I am reading. How did this mod team manage to get so out of touch with the charter of this site?

Comment: @Theo [Here's](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1149151/hnq-hits) a list of a few thousand HNQs. Most all recent posts were removed by Asaf (likely many hundreds if not thousands if the recent pattern of removing all of them persists). I'm confident that almost everyone browsing them will find many Q&As that they believe would be educational to the general public. I'm perplexed as to why most of them were censored.There seems to be no rhyme or reason. It's quite sad and disturbing that the general public was denied the chance to learn from us for this very long period. Read it & weep.

Comment: Btw, for the record, in comments on the above question I asked Asaf many times to provide us with data on his HNQ censorship so that the community could evaluate these actions. He refused to make this easily available, e.g. writing  "It's public data. You are just insisting on being spoon-fed this data." So I had to waste precious time digging up this obscure data. Browsing the data it is clear why he did not want to make it easily available since now everyone can clearly see the tremendous damage done by such censorship. This list deserves broader exposure in a new meta question. Volunteers?

Comment: @Bill for the last couple of comments, maybe if you would have asked nicely and clearly somebody would have helped you. I mean as a baseline,  *you* want the data, *you* go fetch it. The other users here are not under your command. Okay, I understand that you prefer that somebody else waste their time to cater to your wishes, but objectively I find this hard to justify.    Tangentially, you were pointed to the data explorer. Was it really  hard to search for "hnq" there and pick a relevant query?

Comment: Related to the removals as I had commented to @Theo , it is worth noting that some questions make it to HNQ for the sole reason of other questions being removed. There are quotas per site and our site has a relatively big number of potential  HNQs. In practice the question is rather do we control *which* questions from our site get shown and how long, or do we just broadcast whatever gets popular. Managing the HNQ puts more  questions from this site on the HNQ (but for shorter periods of time). One can have different opinions on this but one most not oversimplify the practical ramifications.

Comment: @Bill on your question to me: it was a priori basically clear how the discussion would look like and those that we then had confirmed this. There are then various opinions, yet then we have to decide what we do. Ultimately there is little relevance to a discussion the result of which is certainly inconclusive. Our position, or at least mine, is something along the lines of we manage the HNQ as we see fit until/unless there is considerable opposition against it, at which point we likely mostly stop managing it. What we won't do is sketch out yet another Rube Goldberg machine.

Comment: @quid It seems that you don't appreciate the severity of this matter. This is clearly the largest breach of trust by a mod team that has occurred in the decade this site has existed - even worse than the time that a former math mod knowingly violated the mod contract and divulged confidential user data - possibly damaging the academic career of a student. It's worse because it has caused much more global damage. For around a year or so the entire (SE) world has been robbed of the opportunity of receiving front-page exposure to possibly helpful mathematics.

Comment: No one can know how much damage that caused. It may have prevented budding students from viewing posts that sparked their interest in math. It may have prevented scientists from seeing germs of math ideas that lead to breakthroughs in their field. Both of these could delay the solution of various major problems we face in the world. This is not at all far-fetched. One need only peruse the biographies of leading scientists to understand the crucial role that serendipity plays in cross-pollination of math and science.

Comment: Optimal use of the HNQ increases the chances of such real-world applications of math. Smothering the HNQ destroys all hope of such. The world deserves better chances. Hence my serious concern about such matters.

Comment: @Bill as I explained the *global* exposure of math questions was likely much less reduced than you might imagine. Many a question *only* was on the HNQ *because of* the removals.  Either way I think I have made my point clear. For now the number of users that see a problem seems small.

Comment: @quid  There is no data to support your claim. In any case, if the mod team refuses to take this seriously then I will have no choice but to elevate it to the SE team. As is clear from the above comments, it grossly violates the intended use of such powers (removing *all* HNQs is not using these "big guns sparingly"). I confess that I  am *greatly disappointed* by the above replies from the mod team. I expected much better.

Comment: @Bill obviously there is data.  Just use the query and compare the number of questions on the list over various sites. But, indeed, I recommend that you escalate your concern.

Comment: @quid Even if your argument was well-founded (and I don't believe it is), it has little to do with the concerns I raised. Further my comment did not refer to that but rather to your unfounded claim "the number of users that see a problem seems small". Users cannot complain about what they don't know (and what was hidden from them by choice by the mod team).  And of course few readers peruse the bowels of very long comment threads. Re: your recommendation: it is very sad that is the only choice you can offer in this serious matter.  But maybe it is the correct one.

Comment: @BillDubuque "(removing _all_ HNQs is not using these "big guns sparingly")" was it absolutely completely immensely all?

Comment: @MagicConchShell The [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1149151/hnq-hits) I posted lists a few thousand HNQs. Iiirc I  browsed a few pages of the most recent questions and some random sampling from recent months (probably around 100 total) and they were *all* quickly removed (except the two Asaf mentioned - which are way over the heads of the general public). The end result is essentially that we have not had a hot network list for a long time. If I had to guess based on what I saw it seems the strategy is to remove them all as quickly as possible.

Comment: There are *many* (likely hundreds if not thousands) of those Q&As that many (most?) folks would agree could be educational to the general public. You'll soon realize that if you peruse them. Of course there are some low quality threads too, but that's not a good  excuse to flush the baby with the bath water.

Comment: @MagicConchShell  **Update** It appears that the removal has stopped recently, so you'll need to start on April 2 to see how it was before the above critiques (I just noticed this now).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you so much. I'll check them all

Comment: @Bill: The Data Explorer updates once a week. I did slow down on *some* HNQ removals, but certainly I did not stop it. But I think at this point, it is better if you just complain to SE, and stop posting dramatic comments here and on the chat.

Comment: @Asad How are *facts* "dramatic"?

Comment: @Bill: Well, there were no conspiracies, shadowy decisions, global damage to mathematics as a whole, etc. You're talking about a hypothetical dream situation. I've asked you before to slow down on you imagination, and relax. Your reaction seemed to do the reverse. So I'm asking that you simply escalate your complaints.

Comment: @Asaf  The only person to use the word "conspiracy" anywhere prior above is *you*. Ditto for the other term. Please learn to quote others properly. If you are not able to comprehend the possible ramifications of your extreme censorship, or the fact that some users might be greatly upset by these actions, then I don't know what more to say to help you to open your eyes.

Comment: @Bill: Extreme censorship would have been deleting your comments. And yet, you're allowed to freely scream into the void about how I singlehandedly ruined mathematics and science worldwide. As quid indicated, we foresaw your urge to try and bring any moderating process (of which you are not in complete control) to a grinding halt. This is not the US Senate, there are no filibusters here. As was suggested before, you should probably just escalate your complaints.

Comment: @asaf If you continue to claim that I said thing that I have not then I will refuse to ucommunicate with you. And please  put your crystal ball away.

Comment: @Bill: Are you trying to gaslight me? You just repeatedly wrote that I exercised "extreme censorship" and caused "global damage" and made many users on the SE network not aware of the second largest site. Now you're claiming that you didn't say any of these things? Please, just escalate your complaints and spare us this silly dance.

Comment: @asaf I've lost count of the words you have attempted to put in my mouth above, e.g. " puppet master", "conspiracy". "shadowy", Only you have used these highly loaded terms. I never said anything of the sort. It is impossible to have a rational discussion when you behave like that. Have you not learned anything from the mistakes of the past? I retracted my prior offer since you have made it quite clear that you are not interested in compromising.

Comment: @Bill: You are correct. I should learn from mistakes of the past. Please escalate your complaints. Please stop referring to this as "extreme censorship", and please refrain from using the terms "global damage", at least until you provide *solid* evidence of said damage. There will be no additional communications from this side.

Comment: I'm sad to learn that you aren't more open to understanding the diverse views in this community. I truly believe that there are reasonable compromises that can easily be achieved in this matter. But that is impossible if you never make the effort to communicate with the community before implementing your own personal views - without a word of notice to the community. The site is supposed to be managed *democratically*. What you did to our HNQs is - alas - *quite far* from that.

Comment: @Bill: When a full consensus about *you* being the delegate of the community with whom the moderators need to discuss, we'll talk about that. Until then, goodbye.

Comment: @Asaf So much for hoping that you might stop misquoting me. I never said anything about any "delegate of the community" Rather  I requested that you "communicate with the community". In the past we have always expected that when moderators wish to devise important policy decisions. It is *deeply disturbing* that some members of the current team apparently think that does not apply to them.

Comment: @Bill: Nobody in the moderator team thinks they are above the community. Not since 2012, anyway. We didn't see the HNQ as an important policy, we foresaw that you will go crazy with terms like "extreme censorship" (again, I am not a native speaker, but that sounds like a wild exaggeration to me) or "global damage" (which is definitely speculative). The HNQ topic came up six months ago, we discussed it, there seemed to be no significant problems raised there, and we carried on. Now, we really are at an impasse, so I will stop here, and flag your future replies to me as unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

My intention is that an upvote of this answer indicates agreement with the following statement:

> I am **in favor** of creating a blacklist of terms which will prevent a post from appearing on the HNQ.  The precise composition of that list be determined once we have agreed that such a list should exist in the first place.

---

#### Pontification

What follows are an expression of my opinion, intended to justify my support for the existence of *a* blacklist, and to elicit comments and engender discussion.  Please not that my *intention* is that an upvote to this answer should indicate agreement with the statement above.  One needn't agree with the following in order to agree with the above statement—comments would be an appropriate place (I think) to continue the discussion and voice disagreement with my reasoning.  I considered placing the following in the comments directly after this answer, but, as the writer of the answer, I get the privilege of using my answer to kick of discussion in manner that is less ephemeral than comments.

In general, I am in favor of any proposal which cuts down on the amount of low-quality posts which end up on the HNQ.  My understanding is as follows.

1. Each sub-site is allotted only a finite number of slots on the HNQ (five, with the possibility of reducing that number if the community agrees).
2. We have no lack of active questions which can be promoted to the HNQ.  Hence removing a question from the HNQ does not greatly alter the amount of MSE content that is on the HNQ; it only change *what* content is on the HNQ.
3. The HNQ should be a showcase for the best that MSE has to offer.  However, for various technical and cultural reasons, posts which are not a good reflection of MSE often end up on the HNQ.  For example, no post with MathJax in the title can appear on the HNQ; homework dumps often become quite active because they are easy to understand and easy to answer, even if such questions do not put forward the very best of MSE.

Assuming that the above is true (and that there is general consensus about point 3—perhaps some people have no problem with MSE being (or being portrayed to the wider community as) a site for dumping homework problems), then it makes sense to filter and prune the HNQ somewhat actively.  A list of *verboten* terms is a step in that direction, and is, perhaps, more transparent than the current *status quo*.  However, it seems that we don't yet have consensus even on the idea that there should or could be a blacklist of terms which should be barred from the HNQ (note:  such a list only keeps bad titles off the HNQ; a good question with a bad title can be fixed).

Comment: Presumably, your implicit vote is in favour of the list?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, more or less.  I am in favor of *a* list.  I think that the list compiled in the original post is a reasonable start (though I might remove common verbs such as "simplify" and "solve", but my goal was not to quibble about this yet.).  I tried to make that clear in the quote block was what one might agree to, while the rest was my own personal opinion, which goes to explain why I am in favor of *a* list.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to clarify how the score of this answer should be adjusted.

Comment: +1. I guess this [very recent HNQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616846/finding-zn-sum-i-1n-i2-left-lfloor-fracni2-right-rfloor) can serve as an example for your point 3. (fortunately in this case we don't need moderator removal)

Comment: It might be better to separate into another answer your reasons for being in favour of the proposal. That way one can vote on and discuss your reasons separately from voting on the proposal itself (should people desire to do so).

Comment: This is a dupe of the prior attempt at a poll (with some opinions appended). Duplication in general is bad, even more so when polling. Not to mention polls with opinions added automatically invalidate the poll since they may unfairly influence voting, and further some readers will end up voting on the opinions rather than the question in the poll. It is *essential* to keep the two separate. Besides the time for a poll is long past - the thread is now dormant.

Comment: @Bill: It is not a duplicate, it is a clarification. And if the thread is dormant, then we can just close it and move on with the plan of implementation. It seems that overall we have reasonable support. Very good then, thank you for your help!

Comment: @asaf It seems more like: I don't like the votes on the other poll, so let's try again with some opinions appended to help sway others to my viewpoint. Whether or not that was intended, it may be the effect - which invalidates it. I don't find your attempted joke to be humorous.

Comment: @Bill: If you take a few minutes to read the comments on that answer, instead of antagonising users based on their user name (or user id, I suppose), you'll see that the previous poll answer is problematic due to lack of clarity. Since I cannot close an answer, and since most people are less likely to change their vote after clarification, it is better and fairer to start from scratch. Now, I will ask you this once, do not attempt to hijack this comment thread. I will shoot first and ask later when it comes to removing unnecessary comments (by anyone, not just yours). Say relevant things.

Comment: @asaf Please refrain from making false and misleading accusations. In particular please stop unfoundedly denigrating users whose meta views differ from yours.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Could you do what Brahadeesh suggests?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I've just finished reading your _personal opinion_. It influenced me, now I don't want the filter anymore. It seems to me that one should _vote_ on 'pairs' (filter and list altogether). Because what if we "all" agree with the filter. fine. but then when voting for which lists yes and which not, I think we're going to disagree a lot, maybe to the point of not wanting the filter _at all_ and hence regreting for voting in favour of the filter.

Comment: @Magic_Isa: There's a part of me that feels like your comment is facetious and insincere.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There's a part of me that feels like you're being very disrespectful. And mean because you're just saying mean things without further foundation.

Comment: @BillDubuque The previous attempt at a poll suggested that an upvote meant both supporting the proposal **and** the list.  This is a distinct question, which asks only whether or not one supports, in principle, the idea of a blacklist.

Comment: Then, @Magic_Isa, you should downvote this answer, and upvote the other.  Though I find it strange that you would be opposed to the existence of a list, but in favor of a particular list...

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for clarifying. I think this question puts the cart before the horse. It presumes the community agrees that this is the best way to handle our HNQ but, alas, the community was never asked about such. I think there are much more intelligent ways that we can leverage our diverse knowledge to optimally moderate HNQs. We should go back to square one and solicit ideas on the best way to do such rather than settle for such a primitive solution ...

Comment: ... I suspect we could devise a much better solution that would satisfy most everyone.  At the least, we should take a shot at it before settling on something so suboptimal.

Comment: @BillDubuque I see a lot of criticism of other people's proposals, but I don't see you suggesting an alternative.  Personally, I think that the *best* solution would be to ask / demand SE to allow MathJax titles in HNQ.  Barring that, a blacklist seems reasonable.  If you have a better idea, **please** post a new answer.  I would **love** to know how you think the HNQ should be managed...

Comment: @Xander I just proposed an alternative - start from square one and devise a much better  solution (I have many ideas but this is not the best place to discuss them). I don't see "a lot of other people's proposals". Rather I see only one proposal in this question - to filter by keywords. It does not solicit other ideas from the community.

Comment: @Xander Btw, reading your point (3) (and perusing SE meta) makes it clear that not everyone agrees on what the *purpose(s)* of the HNQ should be (e.g. the "best of MSE" may not be the best to display to readers on other SE sites since it may be *way* over their heads). So even before attempting to devise solutions I think we should solicit opinions on what roles the HNQ should play, Only after that is better understood do we have a good chance of devising a solution that meets all our needs.

Comment: @BillDubuque You say that you have "proposed an alternative - start from square one and devise a much better solution".  This is **not** an alternative.  This amounts to "burn it to the ground, and then..."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106539/discussion-between-xander-henderson-and-bill-dubuque).

Comment: @Bill: We've both been on this site for nearly a decade now. Through that time I've seen you repeatedly suggest to "go back to square one" when policies you disagreed with came up. That's fine, going back to "square one" is an option, and sometimes the best option. But it is not productive to just repeat this when you dislike the outcome. We have to make do with the tools we have. The HNQ is a very flawed tool (for our site), and we need to work with what we got. You've repeatedly complained about misleading scores of posts that reached the HNQ, and we're simply trying to make it easier [...]

Comment: [...] for the algorithm to select questions. What would "square one" be? Redesigning the HNQ? Not gonna happen. We can opt out, or we can opt in, there's hardly any middle grounds here. And if we opt in, we need to work with the tools we are *given*, since we have no control over them or the ability to make new ones. So please, do share with us your "square one" ideas. I'd love to hear about them. I am certain that you will put your dislike of "bad HNQ" questions and your enthusiasm towards this site as a teaching platform to come up with some great ideas.

Comment: @Xander: The problem with MathJax is that it is very load-heavy, and requiring it to load for a list which may or may not contain any MathJax is bad design. Not to mention that other sites use `$` as a symbol, which will now cause a bigger problem of deciding which of those should be rendered, and which should be left as an ASCII character (although this is, of course, not impossible). It seems unlikely that this is going to happen (and also, we're not really in a place to *demand* anything, but we can ask, sure).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Of course.  I hadn't thought about the fact that dollar signs get used for other things---I'm convinced by that argument.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I've already downvote. I've also downvoted the other answer because I don't fully agree with that particular list. Again, I think one should propose filter and a specific list.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'd like to see the proof of your previous claim to me. Otherwise, you should apologize.

Comment: @Magic_Isa You've expressed an opinion, yes.  However, the opinion which you have expressed is not consistent with basic logic.  You don't favor the idea of having a blacklist, but you favor the creation and implementation of a perfect blacklist.  This doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am in favor of having a blacklist if and only if you tell me explicitly  its consistency, otherwise, simply no.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I was reading again this comments and I think my comment just above.. doesn't mean what I meant. I'm giving an example to make my point. Say someone says "want coffee?" my guess is that majority would say  "yes" and a little minority "no". So finally, we all gonna have coffee. But what if, when giving us the cup of coffee it turns out is coffee with butter, coffee with coconut milk, etc. and you simply don't like such coffee varieties, to the point that you regret saying "yes, I want coffee". So that's why one should _known_ first the variety of the coffee that one will have.

Comment: @Magic_Isa Using your analogy, I say to my office mates "I'm going to get coffee.  Does anyone else want some?"  They all chime in and say "Sure!  I could use a cuppa!"  Then I say, okay, I'm going to the hippy vegan place which only serves coffee with kombucha and soy milk.  At that point, you can still say no---no one is going to force you to drink kombucha-soy-coffee.  Similarly, I get the impression that MSE will not move forward on an HNQ filter without seeking further advice from the community.  The question, *in principle*, are you in favor of (or opposed to) a filter for the HNQ?

Comment: If the answer is "I would be in favor of a filter, but only if it is the right filter", then it seems to me that you are *in principle* in favor of a filter.  Your objection does not make sense to me.  I am utterly confused by it.  It is a simple yes/no question, and you can't seem to give a straight answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: It is not really a "simple" yes/no question, although there is probably always a way to "simplify" questions to make it look like a "simple" question with yes/no answer.

Comment: @user170039: But there will have to be some amount of compromise. You can't say "my way or the highway", this is not conducive to maintaining a community.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Exactly my point (only a small correction, we already *are* a community, no?).

Comment: @user170039: You misunderstand me. This is a progress. We first need to establish that people want to have a filter. Then we can work towards a list. Someone saying "I will only vote on a particular list" is telling me that this someone has a list in mind, and is not willing to compromise.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I needed to delete my comment. I do not think that I misunderstood you. I only wanted to point out that we *are* a community and hence no need to "build it up". (I see that you have changed the wording, but this comment is made just to clarify my position.)

Comment: @Magic_Isa Your comments are blatantly self-contradictory. You state that:
$$\text{"I am in favor of having a blacklist if and only if you tell me explicitly its consistency..."}$$
Several explicit blacklists have been proposed. By the above, you are in favor of all of them, because they are explicit. But you also write:
$$\text{" I've also downvoted the other answer because I don't fully agree with that particular list."}.$$
So which is it?

Comment: @Magic_Isa As for your coffe analogy, I find it very poor: The standard follow-up question after *"Coffee?"* is of the sort *"How do you want your coffee?"*. In the case of this analogy, you can be in favor of having *a* list, but still agree or disagree with any *particular* list.

Comment: @Servaes To your 1st comment, did you read my comment right below the one you are quoting? This: "I was reading again this comments and I think my comment just above.. doesn't mean what I meant. I'm giving an example to make my point.  ..."

Comment: @Servaes Let me take once again the coffee example. So most users say "yas!, we want coffee rn" and some users want _a_ coffee, some others _b_ coffee, etc. But some users only want  _x_, _y_, _z_ and they have their _reasons_ for this. And it turns out, finally  the community decide to have _a_, _b_, etc. and _x_ . So, the type of coffee that you'll be drinking will be _a_, _b_, etc. and _x_. In that case, we might want to re-vote again, and ask: "well, this is the final coffee list, wanna join?" why to ask again? Because there'll be a LOT of disagreement

Comment: @Magic_Isa Again, if someone asks "You wanna cuppa?" and I say "Yes", I am not committing myself to drinking whatever drek that person brings me.  I am saying that, *in principle*, I would enjoy some coffee, though I might still refuse a cup if it isn't to my liking.  On the other hand, if I say "No," no further follow-up is needed.  In the actual conversation that we are having, you seem to be saying "No, I don't want a list at all!" but also saying "I want a specific list."  By analogy, you don't want any coffee, but you want a latte.  Your position is incoherent.

Comment: I'm not sure it has been mentionned in the previous comments, but I think your point 1 is slightly wrong. By default every site on the network can have a maximum of five HNQ questions at a time, independently of its size (so we do not have more slots than other sites). Each site can decide to lower that amount (even set it to zero) if the corresponding community wants to, but I don't know if any site has done this (apart from IPS.SE, which apparenlty is limited to one question at a time).

Comment: @ArnaudD.  Ah.  I did not know that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to address some issues I see here.

First, there is an underlying tone of this being an interventionist approach and that opposition is out of principle against interventionism.

That is fair, but if you are against interventionism **out of principle** and you think that such a list is an intervention, then you should be against the HNQ too. (A disclaimer: I am not against the HNQ.)

Why? The HNQ involves *an algorithm with some parameters that displays questions which satisfy those parameters with more prominence*.

This list involves *an algorithm with some parameters that avoids displaying some questions which satisfy those parameters with more prominence*.

The actions are the same in nature, the intention is different, but interventionism is defined by the actions (or perhaps absence thereof or not) and objects, not the intentions, regardless if they are understood as positive or negative. A political analogy is that if someone is against interventionism out of principle, then they ought to be against both government helping companies which are well-established and/or companies which are in bankruptcy. They should not help big businesses, nor small ones.

One can say that they are against **manual** intervention, which is what Asaf is/has been doing, and that is fine, but:

1. **This is not what this topic is about.**
2. If anything, this topic is precisely a way to avoid or lessen the manual intervention which you oppose.

It is somewhat frustrating that people are conflating Asaf's actions with the maintenance of such a list and lumping all kinds of things together. It looks like a knee-jerk reaction and it is adding a lot of noise to the discussion.

There are now two possible branches of reply which I can see:

1. "Well, you see, the HNQ has always been here, so it is natural to me. Such a list is new, so it is an intervention."
2. "OK, but that is a bad intervention, whereas the HNQ is a good one because it helps displaying what our community thinks is best."

Branch 1 is just silly. To elaborate more: if you follow branch 1, you are not against interventionism, you are against changing the *status quo*, which is entirely different and not that much helpful when we are discussing... changes. Regarding 2, do you honestly think that adding things such as "urgent" or "ASAP" is bad intervention? I mean, honestly? If yes, then fine... but please understand and acknowledge that this is not *out of principle* in the sense mentioned previously. It is for some reason that I don't understand, and I am still waiting for a sensible explanation.

Comment: It seems that people are also deluding themselves in how useful/good the algorithm is. It is just as, if not more, biased (the inherent trust people seem to put in it makes it all the more worse). I would trust basically anyone that that has the ability to recognize high quality good questions, which you can recognize even if a particular question isn't your cup of tea, than some stupid algorithm―which is an auto filter btw. If there are not enough good questions which have a certain amount of quality what does that say about the site?

Answer (score 1):

**Proposal:**  MSE should have an auto-filter.  That filter should consist of the string `*`.

(Look!  I've answered the question.  This answer is therefore *technically* on-topic.  And as we all know, that is the best kind of on-topic.  Having *technically* answered the question, I'm going to go off the rails a little.)

[image]

In other words, remove Mathematics StackExchange from the HNQ.

The majority of the best questions on MSE are already ineligible for the HNQ because they contain MathJax in the title.  The StackExchange network is unwilling to implement any kind of technical fix for this (and there is a quite reasonable argument that technical fix is more complicated than it is worth).  As such, the HNQ already fails to be a showcase for the best of what MSE has to offer.

Indeed, my rough impression is that the HNQ is primarily driven by routine homework exercises.  A common path to the HNQ is that a mathematically immature or unsophisticated<sup>[1]</sup> user will post a verbatim question from some homework assignment.  Several FGITW users will very quickly provide answers to the question, while a few other users use the comments to elicit improvement from the original asker.  The answers, being correct solutions to the stated problem, are upvoted, and the question appears on the HNQ a few hours later.

I do not believe that MSE should be (or be known as) a homework dump.  As such, homework problems rarely belong on the HNQ<sup>[2]</sup>.  Unfortunately, the HNQ broadcasts to the rest of SE community that MSE is exactly that:  a dumping ground for homework problems.

Moreover, I don't really see an upside to participating in the HNQ.  We don't need the traffic (MSE is already one of the most active SEs, and students taking classes is a huge driver of traffic).  What benefit does MSE gain from participation?

Perhaps it is time to abandon the HNQ altogether?

---

[1] Note that "mathematically immature and unsophisticated" is not a critique of the *level* of the question being asked.  I have had precalculus students who show tremendous maturity in their write-ups of homework problems, and have read draft Ph.D. theses which look like they were written by a third-grader.  Rather, it is a critique of the quality of the presentation.

[2] It should be noted that Physics SE has an explicit "No Homework" policy.  I have often wondered by MSE does not have a similar policy, but it seems like the ship sailed on that one long before I got an account.

Comment: Dreams of utopia... :-)

Comment: "In other words, remove Mathematics StackExchange from the HNQ." due to "my rough impression is that the HNQ is primarily driven by routine homework exercises." ?

Comment: Let's suppose it's 100% true. So would be better to not to show _a  part_ of what math.stack consists just because the best of the best from math.stack cannot be shown on the HNQ? // Could not be that, a person, picked on the 'homework and unsophisticated and mathematically immature title' and then decide to give a try, to check what's else is on math.stack?

Comment: It seems to me that there'll be lower chances for people to discover the _best of the best_ from math.stack when removing math.stack from the HNQ. And higher chances for people to discover the _best of the best_ from math.stack when not removing math.stack from the HNQ; just my thought tho.

Comment: @Magic_Isa You claim if MSE departs the HNQ, then the best of what MSE will no longer be visible to the rest of the SE community.  This does not address any of my concerns.  My claims are that (1) the HNQ is dominated by homework dumps, (2) the best questions rarely make it to the HNQ because the best questions typically have MathJax in the title, and (3) MSE does not need the traffic generated by the HNQ---the site is already very active.  As MSE derives very little benefit from the HNQ, and the HNQ seems to actively cause harm, maybe it is time to stop participating.

Comment: That being said, I don't intend to reply to you any more.  You have made your opinions quite clear over several threads, and I am tired of your attempts to dominate the conversation.

Comment: Since this is the largest website, other than StackOverflow itself, I'm not sure that the rest of SE is somehow oblivious to the existence of this website. It's a weak argument.

Comment: @XanderHenderson "You claim if MSE departs the HNQ, then the best of what MSE will no longer be visible to the rest of the SE community." No. I never claimed this. I said "It seems to me that there'll be lower chances.." _lower chances_

Comment: @Magic_Isa I apologize.  You made a claim that is weaker and less convincing than the one I attributed to you. (That is, the claim "If MSE leaves the HNQ, then outsiders **won't** see the best of MSE" is a much stronger argument in favor of staying on the HNQ than "If MSE leaves the HNQ, then outsiders are **less likely** to see the best of MSE.")  Thank you for helping me to make my case.

Comment: I think I've already countered all of these points in my answer. First, the HNQ is not for users like you or I, so you don't have to see the upside for you. Second, the homework dumpers read nothing, including site guidelines, all the warnings when you post a question, etc. Third, nobody on the network thinks the HNQ is a badge of approval! I get why you wouldn't want to engage with homework dumpers, but I don't really understand the need to eliminate them at all costs (particularly to 99.9% of our first year or lower students). Can't you just focus on the questions/tags you'd rather answer?

Comment: @Theo: There's a bigger picture at play here. When you feel increasingly warmer, but all you care about is just your computer, you're going to miss when your house is on fire. The average quality of questions and answers is going down. Some people don't want to "just focus on the questions they'd rather answer". Some people want to focus also on the image of the this site in the public's eye. And in particular, the academic world's eye. This can be a great venture for outreach, but not if everyone sees it as a cheating database.

Comment: @Asaf I very recently told the senior academic in charge of tutorial allocations that I used to be a regular contributor to MSE. The context was, he was training me in using Piazza, some software for answering questions online. His first response: "Uh-oh". I had to quickly divorce myself from the anti-PSQ mindset, at which point he relaxed. My point is, I don't think this anti-PSQ stance, when it alienates elmentary students, is actually putting this site in a positive light. I really hesitate to recommend it to anyone these days. It feels like a wannabe MO, which is not really a good look.

Comment: @Asaf Despite this, I did try recommending MSE to my students before my uni closed. My students all seemed to be under the impression that MSE punishes "dumbass questions". That is, if the question was too simple, you'd be abused by the users. I tried correcting them, but honestly, I couldn't even properly convince myself that this wasn't the case. I know it's not the way the guidelines are designed, but it is the reality of the situation. MSE's reputation seems to be suffering, not just in the eyes of academics, but the eyes of students. We seem hellbent on becoming totally irrelevant.

Comment: @Asaf Finally, is the average quality of questions going down because we get fewer "good" questions, or because we get more "bad" questions? We are getting more popular (especially now, during the pandemic), which, on average, brings far more elementary students without the mathematical maturity to ask questions we like. If you're picking at random, of course you're more likely to find a "bad" question. If you're filtering based on tags, are "good" questions actually harder to find?

Comment: @TheoBendit It seems rather selfish (to me) to focus exclusively on a couple of tags in which I am personally interested while ignoring the overall health of the site.  I have no problem with selfishness like this---different users want to interact with the site differently, and no harm comes from it.  However, it is somewhat galling to be told that we shouldn't bother with the overall health of the site, because it is possible to bury our heads in the metaphorical sand of a couple of tags.

Comment: And, again:  who benefits from the inclusion of MSE in the HNQ?

Comment: @Xander It's funny, because I see an entirely different kind of selfishness. I see a potentially enormous resource for mathematical help held hostage by snobbery; the personal tastes of a few thousand preventing this site from helping millions. I see people saying we should junk the HNQ just because they don't see how it helps them personally. What I don't see is a crisis of "site health". The site seems relatively healthy to me, full of people seeking and finding the maths they need. The biggest threat to our site's health is irrelevancy.

Comment: @Theo: When one tends to focus only on the questions they want to answer, one tends not see anything other than that.

Comment: @Xander As for your specific question, the HNQ helps people in the SE network who aren't regulars at MSE, by exposing them to interesting pieces of maths. It helps the maths community, as all mathematics outreach does, when mathematics piques the general public's interest. Maths anxiety is a simply enormous problem, not just for students afflicted by it, but mathematics in general. More outreach is sorely needed. We need to show the public that mathematics is interesting, welcoming, and relevant. Otherwise, there goes pure maths funding.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'd appreciate if you could wait 10 minutes, before accusing me of ignoring questions.

Comment: @Theo: Very well, let me start a timer. Or do you want to ping me again in 6 minutes?

Comment: @TheoBendit You claim that "the HNQ helps people in the SE network who aren't regulars at MSE, by exposing them to interesting pieces of maths".  However, the argument that I (and others) have been making is that the HNQ most decidedly does *not* do this.  The HNQ promotes homework dumps.

Comment: You then say "The biggest threat to our site's health is irrelevancy."  How relevant can MSE be if it is flooded with low-quality homework dumps?  These  kinds of questions pollute search, split answers across innumerable duplicates, and make it *harder* to find relevant answers.

Comment: @XanderHenderson "The HNQ promotes homework dumps." How? What evidence do you have that any significant portion of the homework-dumpers have read another question on the site, let alone a HNQ?

Comment: "How relevant can MSE be if it is flooded with low-quality homework dumps?  These kinds of questions pollute search, split answers across innumerable duplicates, and make it *harder* to find relevant answers." I think it could be very relevant, moreso than the search function (which is already functionally unusable to a layman, due to MathJax). It could be a place to get personalised help and support. We could link to dupes where appropriate, delete narrow/otherwise useless answers as we have been, but the focus should be, IMHO on help and support.

Comment: @Theo: Let me tell you about my experience, which is more of a mixed bag. Plenty of mathematicians I've talked to referred to MSE as "mostly homework" or "uninteresting". And I saw a lot of my peers, when I was a student, literally calling it a homework dump (plenty of others used it, it was a mixed bag). The truth is that the average quality of question is getting lower, I now spend most of my time closing questions (often as duplicates) rather than answering them. And as a moderator, I rather not confine myself to a few tags, thank you.

Comment: @Asaf That makes sense. My academic career has not really started, but out of the two unis I've worked for, my experience has been that this attitude towards students is perceived very negatively. In general, the trend towards teaching first year students or lower at these two unis has been to adapt to the students, rather than imposing high standards and functionally ignoring those who fail to step up to the challenge. This approach has plenty of serious problems, but the academics who have adopted the latter approach have not fared well.

Comment: @Theo: I'm sorry that you had an environment like that. In both my graduate degrees the environment was fairly supportive towards students. I can't quite say about my current university, as I am not involved with teaching in any capacity.

Comment: @Asaf I'm honestly pretty on the fence about it. There's a terrible tug-of-war between amount of content taught, and student feedback/engagement. I used to be firmly on the content side, but having tutored students for over 10 years now, I really can appreciate how adapting can actually get the less gifted students learning. The problem with prioritising content is that we tend not to teach students mathematical skills, rather weed out the less gifted ones through attrition, and as you might imagine, that doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: @TheoBendit You ask for evidence:  [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o9__kRB1tfvPaQ3xwxTr9oQB_TuPexZiYBubxgjzufc/edit?usp=sharing) contains the 100 most recent HNQs.  The classification is my own; others are free to see what they think.  By my count, 70 are essentially homework problems (some are better questions than others, and other people have different opinions about whether or not "an attempt" adds useful context).  13 of the 100 questions have been closed.  29 of the questions have (or had) uninformative titles---many of those questions are no longer on the HNQ.

Comment: I should also note that not all of the non-PSQ (problem statement question) posts are of high quality; there are only 16 of the 100 posts which I think are uncontroversially adequate (those are the posts labeled "Good").  Some of the posts labeled "???" might also be a good reflection of MSE (not in my opinion, but opinions vary).  Finally, not all of the PSQs are necessarily of low quality, though the best *questions* have been removed from the HNQ by title edits which added MathJax.

Comment: These questions were found via the SEDE query https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1075209/questions-which-were-in-hnq . Tip of the hat to [@PaulPlummer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31519/468350).

Comment: @Xander I specifically asked for evidence that these questions in the HNQ are causing people to post PSQs. The various inherent biases in the HNQ mean that we are definitely going to see more "lower quality" posts there; this has been discussed to death (and I'm still unconvinced it' a problem). Again, I don't think the people posting PSQs are big readers of the site. I don't think they read "How to ask a good question", then look at a HNQ, and based on finding some PSQ in the HNQ, they think they don't need to follow the rules.

Comment: @TheoBendit How do you see the spreadsheet? what is your point of view about it?

Comment: @Magic_Isa I don't have strong feelings one way or another about the spreadsheet. It didn't surprise me that the HNQ is full of PSQs. I've explained a few times why the HNQ is biased towards more elementary students (which I think is good), and why more elementary students are more likely to post PSQs. If anything, $16\%$ being "uncontroversially adequate" was a slightly higher proportion than I was expecting.

Comment: @TheoBendit Then I think you misunderstood my claim.  When I said that the HNQ promotes homework dumps, I mean that it is homework dumps which are bumped up to the HNQ and used as promotion for MSE, not that the HNW encourages people to post homework dumps (that is a much harder thing to measure).

Comment: @TheoBendit "If anything, 16% being 'uncontroversially adequate' was a slightly higher proportion than I was expecting."  So, basically, you claim that you do not expect any more than 16% of the HNQ to consist of good posts.  That is, the part of the site which is supposed to showcase the **best that MSE has to offer** is 80%+ crap.  How does this benefit **anyone**?  Also, I addressed your point about "elementary" questions in my post.

Comment: @TheoBendit Oh ok, thanks. I do also think it is good that the HNQ is biased towards more elementary students :) although I have to say that I've seen very advanced questions with a title that I've no idea what the question will be about, on the HNQ

Comment: @XanderHenderson Because it is the best that MSE has to offer, just not the best of what it has to offer regular contributors like you. We're offering mathematics relevant to the people who don't regularly attend our site; we're not offering templates for superior formatting. Don't forget, it's *you*, not them, that's calling it crap. For non-regulars (almost all of which are very elementary in terms of mathematics ability), the questions moderators are currently tolerating on the HNQ are crap. Beautifully formatted, totally incomprehensible, irrelevant, uninteresting crap.

Comment: @XanderHenderson As I said in my answer, if you want to display what you, as a regular, think is the best of MSE, then post some bounties. That's where regulars can advertise the best of MSE to people who will appreciate it.

Comment: @TheoBendit [This is the best that MSE has to offer?!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3610588/can-we-make-an-infinite-sequence-of-primes-adding-one-digit-to-the-left)

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sure. It's a kinda neat problem that anybody on just about any level could get into. Once you stop judging a question primarily by its format (which can be changed), things don't tend to look so bleak.

Comment: @Theo: It does look worse once you judge it by the presentation, i.e. the way the question is presented. I completely agree with Xander here. Why are you so willing to compromise and show mediocre content? When people apply for a grant they are expected to write the best proposal they can write, and they hope to be judged by that quality (whether or not the judgement is biased by author or otherwise is a different story). To quote Prof. Hubert Farnsworth *"penmanship counts"*. We have so much more to offer, why are you so insistent on settling down?

Comment: The difference is here, @Asaf, is that you've appointed yourself as judge. This is not a grant that you've funded, and you are protecting your investment by weeding out lesser penmanship. This is a feature of the SE network, in which you've repeatedly admitted to not seeing the value (Xander too), and now you are trying to mold according to your wishes (at great expense). I'm not compromising anything, except your own, largely unsolicited, self-imposed standards. Leave it alone. It functions better without you.

Comment: @TheoBendit "which can be changed" How about you do such things with some frequency? Talk is cheap.

Comment: @Theo: How is it my own if Xander and others are supportive of this approach? How come for years now people (including Bill, I might add) complained about the undeserved votes HNQ posts receive, which then lead people to argue "it's highly voted, therefore it is good and on topic" (you can see this approach used in this very discussion to justify "advice", even though advice as a whole is not even on topic anymore). I don't know what is the great expense, other than some people having higher scores, I honestly think you're exaggerating.

Comment: @TheoBendit MSE is not social media and it is not a tutoring site.  If people want to discuss problems or homework, there are other places on the internet for that:  Facebook, reddit, Quora, Khan Academy, etc.  What MSE seeks to do is to create a searchable database of questions and answers.  Yes, the helping the asker in the moment is good, but helping future questioners in the future is better.  Thus formatting counts.  Better formatted text is easier to search.  Informative titles are easier to search.

Comment: It appears that your goal is to tutor individuals.  If that is the case, then I will give you the same advice that you gave to @AsafKaragila:  "Leave it alone. It functions better without you."

Comment: @quid *I did*, when I was regularly contributing to the site. I paid little attention to the maths HNQ specifically (again, it wasn't for me), but I would fix up poorly-formatted posts all the time, and would regularly try to solicit context from elementary askers as gently as I could.

Comment: @TheoBendit the number of your edits says otherwise. Maybe a few times.

Comment: @quid Huh, my number of edits is lower than I thought it would be. I remember frequently performing edits like adding in MathJax and removing images while writing out the contents. Whatever; the point is that changing the formatting of a question is an alternative to freaking out about a low-quality question making it onto the HNQ.

Comment: @TheoBendit alright, but that should cut both ways. If the title is edited to  a reasonable one, it will not be blocked anyway.

Comment: @quid I'm not sure what's cutting both ways here, or why. I don't follow your point, honestly. An automatic blocking list means that various popular question will not make it onto the list, just because of some easily-correctable minor cosmetic defect. Are you saying that I should be editing every title proactively, to remove the block list words, in case such questions could become "hot"? That sounds like a full-time job.

Comment: @TheoBendit of course no one user could, *but* for a question to become a HNQ in the first place a relevant number of users need to answer it and/or vote on it. *Anyone* of these users could edit the post (or at least propose the edit), which apparently they find relevant. If of these, say, ten users none did care enough to do this, maybe they do not really care all that much about the thread. Yes some might be new, not know, etc. But many don't care to improve things much, just say it could be done. (I'm not most active editor either, but I'm also more in the 'don't polish a turd' camp.)

Comment: @quid "for a question to become a HNQ in the first place a relevant number of users need to answer it and/or vote on it. Anyone of these users could edit the post (or at least propose the edit), which apparently they find relevant." I concede that this is a very good point. I'll say again, if we really must make a block list, then let's make it one where every word in the block list can be edited out without damaging the question.

Comment: @Asaf Myself and Bill have talked about the "great expense"; I still believe the HNQ has great potential for outreach. You've expended plenty of your time, ensuring that the HNQ reaches out to as few people as possible, and now you want help through crude technological measures. I have another solution...

Comment: @XanderHenderson I think it is a maths tutoring site, and you're in some level of denial about it. This solution of having a bunch of questions which people can search through to find answers doesn't really work in the context of maths. For an elementary student, the search function is basically useless. Even if they somehow find something similar, they often don't have the skill to synthesise the answer to the variant problem and apply the logic to their own problem. They need individual help, even if it's just individual help finding the previous questions they need to see.

Comment: @Xander Again, I'm not advocating against deletion. I think it's an important part of the process, making it easier for our regulars to search for duplicates. I think we can have both functions work: an FAQ that sufficiently au fait users can search through, and a tutoring site for people who need individual help. That's how it's working now.

Comment: @TheoBendit Your contention that MSE "is a maths tutoring site" is contradicted by the FAQ, the software on which the site runs (see the various close reasons which seek to eliminate PSQs, such as a requirement of more context or a stricture against duplicating questions (by the way, the HNQ question I linked to above was not only a low quality PSQ, it was also a duplicate many times over)), and numerous posts on meta discussing the role that MSE should play in the wider world.

Comment: I would also point out that many of the current moderators were elected after answering questions about PSQs in a way that displayed a clear antipathy towards these no context questions.  If you are going to argue that MSE is a tutoring site, you are going to have to acknowledge that you are a member of a rather extreme minority, and that your point of view is not shared by the majority of those users who are active on meta.

Comment: E.g. [Aloizio Macedo](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28778/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/28782#28782) took a pretty hard line, while [Asaf Karagila](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28807/468350) didn't really take a stand, but seemed to indicate that he believes that both extremes are wrong, and that some middle ground should be found.

Comment: I think I'm going to stop replying, as this thread is making me angry, and I'm doing none of us here any favours by continuing to post. I want to thank @Asaf in particular for being fair with me. I know you hold strong opinions, but I've been impressed by your restraint, and any time I detected a little less respect, I concede it was somewhat deserved.

Comment: @Theo: Thank you for your participation. And you're very welcome.

Comment: @TheoBendit "Huh, my number of edits is lower than I thought it would be." just to note that your real number of edits might not be 281, as shown in your profile activity. If you have an _edit approved_ somewhere, you could click there and then click on (more) and then you'll see a different number of edits. e.g. [mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRrUn.png) however on my profile activity shows only 211 edits. \\ This is also for future readers, so that they could see that Theo's _real_ contributions are not  precisely the ones displayed in his profile

Answer (score -1):

Although this would require more work to implement, consider that instead of posts being excluded based on the autofilters just not appearing on the HNQ list, they are also placed in a separate list. Then somebody (at least the moderators, but perhaps it can also be accessed by certain other members, e.g., ones with particularly high reputations) can occasionally, if and when they wish to, check these items to see if any should actually be considered for the HNQ. If so, then perhaps the easiest way to have them be reconsidered is just for the person to edit the title in such a way that it's no longer excluded from the HNQ.

To avoid having too many items in this list, especially ones which no longer would reasonably be considered for the HNQ anyway, perhaps have them age off after some period of time, e.g., a few hours or perhaps a day or so.

Note if nobody ever looks at this list, then with all else being equal (e.g., the list of terms for the autofilter is not different based on this feature being available) the behavior would be effectively the same as without this feature, so there's not much downside in that respect. However, having this extra list does help to address certain concerns, such as mentioned in the question comments, about otherwise good questions not being included just due to their titles containing one or more words that are being filtered out.

Note I don't have, or claim to, enough knowledge and experience with the questions involved which should, or should not, reasonably be on the HNQ to state whether or not this additional option would be worth the implementation effort and considering how often it's expected anybody will check this list. I'm just proposing it here so other members, especially ones who are more knowledgeable about this than me, can give their feedback and opinions.

**Update:** I believe a fairly reasonable option to consider for anybody other than moderators to see the list is for other members to see *only* the questions with tags where they have a gold tag badge (i.e., as described in [Badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges), "You must have a total score of $1000$ in at least $200$ non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge."). As they already are believed to be quite expert in this area, so they can for example single-handedly mark these questions as duplicates and reopen as needed, they should also be able to tell, better than most other members (including moderators), which questions are quite good & how to best possibly change the titles so the questions may appear on the HNQ.

You may also consider adding other restrictions, e.g., requiring a reputation of at least $20000$ so they're considered a "trusted user". However, I suspect the large majority of gold tag badge holders would already meet any requirement like that.

Comment: Yes, in an ideal world, we would have curators voting for HNQ posts. This is not the case. This is a fairly fast-paced automatic process. I am very much in favour of an actual quorum that selects good posts from a variety of topics from the last X days/weeks/months and publishes it somewhere. But this is a whole other thing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree that, in an ideal world, the implementation for the HNQ would be quite different, such as your suggestion of using a quorum to select among recent good posts. Nonetheless, I made my suggestion as I believe it can be implemented more quickly & easily than making other more significant changes, and it would help to mitigate some of the concerns about having just a group of autofilters to decide on being on the HNQ list.

Comment: I think that the idea is to somehow give a picture of what is "trending", and in that sense, trending means topics that have a lot of positive activity. But positive activity can be generated by a small number of users working in unison (not necessarily in a malicious way). Mathematics is different this way, as a science too, it is slower, more thought out, and requires more attention. Usually, anyway. This is one of the reasons I feel that HNQ is usually not helpful to our community. Most questions caught by the algorithm are either just bad, or shouldn't be representatives of this site.

Comment: The autofilters are just what I can tell would be helpful from my experience monitoring this in the last months (year?) since the manual removal feature was introduced.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've not been a member as long, or been as involved as you, but I get the impression an important reason for the HNQ is to help show, and promote to, the members that there are wide variety of other sites on the SE network than just programming ones, especially Stack Overflow. To help do this, they're trying to show a wide variety of possible interesting questions but, unfortunately, their selection mechanism is based mainly, as you state, on a lot of positive activity. Nonetheless, I believe the issue is not the HNQ is not useful for this community, but just there are ...

Comment: @AsafKaragila (cont.) unfortunately too many relatively poor questions from math which make it to the HNQ. I suspect this is a similar issue, to varying degrees, with many other sites, and not just ones which are science based. I believe it's helpful to have math questions on the HNQ, but ideally better quality ones, so in that respect, I believe my suggestion would be helpful as an adjunct to using various autofilters as you suggest.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because, as it stands, it doesn't seem to be useful. I think it may be a good idea which I'd like to be true/tested out, but it seems to me that there is very little chance that this could be implemented in the foreseeable future. (I believe "very little" is an understatement.)

Answer (score -1):

**I support the proposal.**

- Please consider **upvoting** this post if you agree with the proposal of the question & the current proposed list. Else **downvote**.

Comment: I removed the earlier post because it is redundant.

Comment: If one agree with this, then one also agree with the current proposal list? Or is it just an agreement with the 'pure new change' and the _list thing_ will be discussed in another time?

Comment: @Magic_Isa: Answer to the first question: both.

Comment: ohh, then I'd have to downvote because there are words in that list that I don't agree with removing them, for example _puzzle_. However there are some words that I support their removal, for example _urgent_

Comment: This is ultimately unhelpful. We can change the list, it's not a one-off request. So the question should first be, is there a community support for *a* list. Then we start weeding things out of the proposed list in the post itself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I support the proposal but not the list (entirely). And regarding the _list_ I was thinking in voting for each word itself.

Comment: @Magic_Isa: I think that we can partition the list into chunks and vote on the chunks. Some words seem to be agreed by most (e.g. "urgent") and others are more controversial (e.g. "puzzle").

Comment: @AsafKaragila indeed, that would more practical

Comment: @lonestudent: Without going into politics too much, referendums tend to be terrible when there's a binary choice about a broad subject. Just look at the mess created by Brexit. Not to mention that with a small sample size you can't say a lot if you have very close equilibrium (e.g. less than a 10% difference in votes) which tends to happen on meta (with its limited active voters), and that arguably changes to the status quo requires more than a simple majority.

Comment: @lonestudent yes. It's like in the elections. So this should work too.

Comment: @lonestudent "And voting should be done at a certain level of reputation." What's the minimum that you think should be?

Comment: @lonestudent: There's no way to enforce "level of reputation" without having an open vote by editing the post itself. Which will lead a lot of people who try to keep "voting only" approach to meta (and this is the majority of visitors to meta to my understanding), or prefer to keep their preference secret to not vote, and it may cause race condition issues with edits. So all in all, very not great.

Comment: @Magic_Isa If there is no "theft in voting", then zero reputation.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I tried to understand your comment as much as my English allowed. What I meant was to provide everyone to see this post and to prevent "theft of votes"..Upvote/Downvote with fake accounts and etc.

Comment: @lonestudent I see. Even if that happens, I'd assume would be minority, I mean who would spend a lot of time in "theft voting"? a little minority, in general people have millions of thing to do

Comment: @lonestudent: Voting fraud is a problem in general, but we hope that at least on meta it is not very prevalent, as most users who commit voting fraud are normally interested in reputation, of which there is none on meta.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I understand. But isn't there an option to "pin" your post which requiring voting.? Wouldn't it be better for everyone to see this post?

Comment: @lonestudent: No, there is no such option.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Probably. In which case, why don't you edit the post?

Comment: @user170039: We were waiting for the discussion to settle, and for users to comment on the idea, and on the list.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: In that case I don't understand how this can be unhelpful. Can you be more specific? For example, you wrote, "So the question should first be, is there a community support for a list.". Why not edit the question to include only *this* and see how it goes?

Comment: @user170039: Of the +9 voters, it is unclear, who is just in favour of a filter, and who is also in favour of the list, and who is in favour of *some* part of the list. Similarly for the -9 voters, are they against *all* filtration, or just the word "puzzle", or anything else?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Indeed. That's why a rewording is necessary. Otherwise, I don't see much value in this post.

Comment: @AsafKaragila +9 users support the filter, and only the filter, and -9 don't support the filter, this is according to the aclaration in the comments by user 170039.

Comment: @Magic_Isa: You just as well vote about "should we have some lunch?" in a thread that specify "pizza" as a lunch option. Do you mean to say that you're pro-lunch *and* pro-pizza, or just pro-lunch, or just pro-pizza? Or are you against lunch altogether, or just against pizza as lunch, or just generally anti-pizza? It is not helpful to understand the overall minute differences when posing a broad yes/no question like that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I meant both lunch and pizza _but_ not just pizza because there are many different flavours. And one should vote for this flavours

Comment: @Magic_Isa: And how does that help to the discussion, when a significant part of what I want to know is what do people *want* for lunch, not just if they want to join or not. Note that the question *here* is "agree with the proposal". **Which part of it?**

Comment: @AsafKaragila ah. And where do we say that? Do we post an answer? Didn't you say that you were going to partition the list into chunks and so users would vote on the chunks?

Comment: @Magic_Isa: What I said was that we were waiting for the discussion to get to some conclusion. Unfortunately the overall discussion was hijacked into a typical meta argument, and most people simply walked away from it. Whether or not that was the intended goal, or if it will produce the wanted outcome is hard to tell. But I'd still want to wait for a bit longer before moving forward with this.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Irrespective of the outcome of this meta post, will the fate of this meta post (and outcomes thereof) be determined according to what is written, i.e., "discussion phase (until April 30) → escalation phase → implementation stage"? Also I am wondering what do you mean by "wanted outcome". Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user170039: If this proposal is very clearly disliked by the community, or if there are some words on the filter list that even after clarification on the moderators' side, remain unfavourable, this will change the outcome, obviously. This is not a rubber stamp process. The wanted outcome is to get feedback that is *useful* to the moderators.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Definition of "very clear"?

Comment: @user170039: I don't want to define "very clear". If it is very clear, it will be very clear.

Comment: @AsafKaragila but at some point, users will have the opportunity to vote on -posted answers- on which words are acceptable and which aren't, right?

Comment: @Magic_Isa: Yes, that is the idea, to some extent.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Interesting response indeed. It would also be enlightening to know the definition of "feedback that is *useful* to the moderators" (at least for this specific meta post).

Comment: @user170039: I'm not sure what more can I say here. I've repeatedly explains that useful feedback is suggestions to include more words, or remove certain words, or not use a filter altogether, or asking for the reasoning to include certain words on the list. But it seems that this discussion is going in circles now. So I will stop.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would remove this words: question, the following, urgent, opinion, please, and help. (Some of this words, IMO, are fine _but_ aren't fine according to the site's rules). The rest of the words are fine.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've just noticed that I've made a mistake in a previous comment.. "+9 users support the filter, and only the filter, and -9 don't support the filter" I meant "+9 users support the filter and the current list, and -9 don't support this"

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by the idea of changing what is voted on after the vote started: Of course in theory users can change the vote, but they might not realize. In any case if one would want to organize a vote a dedicated thread would be the way to go.

Comment: @quid you're free to revert the edit. I edited to avoid future confusions. This 'specification' of what your vote really means was already mentioned in the comments

Comment: @Magic_Isa I don't have an issue with that edit. There was a proposal that went beyond that, namely to move away from a vote on the list to a vote on the general principle, which is quite different. Anyway it's  mostly moot.

Answer (score -5):

I don't know how many people share my view, but I think if it is a minority it is certainly not a small one based on the vote counts of the answers to this question at this time.

I don't think there should be any autofilters to remove hot network questions, and I also don't think any moderators should be tampering with the hot network questions manually. In practice, what ends up remaining are what the moderators think are good questions, and this is not what moderators are for. Moderators are not supposed to impose their views, they are there to handle exceptional problems that regular users cannot deal with. I don't count certain types of questions being on the list of hot network questions as being exceptional problems.

The terms to filter out that have been proposed are, in my opinion, ludicrously general. I'd be happy to review examples provided by the moderators that they think warranted removal, but the probability that I'll disagree is very close to $1$, especially considering this list.

On prompting by a moderator I will note that I disagree with having a list at all since I don't think hot network questions should be filtered out, period. I think the algorithm should be allowed to select the questions.

Comment: @Magic Maybe you should post an answer.

Comment: There *is* a filter already, called MathJax. It was used, repeatedly, before the existence of the current moderator tool. I will provide you a small sample of examples tomorrow morning, if you'd like.

Comment: @Asaf Abused you mean. And sure, you can provide a list of examples that I'll probably disagree with. Thanks.

Comment: I am not going to bother. I reserve my efforts to people who are willing to change their mind.

Comment: @Asaf It's up to you. I did say "probably." I concede that there may be questions so bad that they should be removed, I'm just skeptical because I haven't seen any and I check often.

Comment: Well, actually, I'd say based on the vote count it is a rather small minority that cares at all about the question.  Votes cast either way are  surprisingly low. What do you think about the filters we have on titles that prevent certain questions from being posted in the first place? Should those be deactivated?

Comment: @quid I don't in principle disagree with filters that entirely prevent questions from being posted. I would assume these would filter out things like offensive words.

Comment: @MattSamuel that's however not at all what they do. Further, On your other remark of 'I concede' that misses the point. The point was that as a matter of fact since many years questions actively are removed from the HNQ via title edits. This undermines "Until recently moderators had no power to remove questions from the list and no one was harmed." since as a matter of fact everybody in the know had the power to remove and *users* (including mods) did make use of this when they thought it useful.

Comment: @quid I see what you mean. I have removed that line.

Comment: @quid By the way, is there a way I can see the blacklist for question titles?

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21966/which-are-blacklisted-tags-and-blacklisted-phrases also see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16573/should-the-site-have-an-automatic-word-filter-for-titles (Important note: maybe I overstated it, and we for now only have warnings and real blocks as they have on SO)

Comment: Matt, abusing the MathJax "hack" would be just adding `${}$` to remove a question from the HNQ. Calling a systematic improvement and clarification of the titles an abuse is ridiculous. Nobody was abusing the MathJax hack. You are free to peruse the Data Explorer lists of questions removed from the HNQ. Yes, I am quite aggressive in my use of this feature, and you may not agree with all of it. But there are plenty of questions that were closed or edited (to have MathJax in the title) by the time I see them (at which point I normally remove from HNQ to ensure nobody reverses the edits).

Comment: Half your answer is off-topic, even though as I mentioned in another comment can contain valid points. More precisely, this bit: "and I also don't think any moderators should be tampering with the hot network questions manually." up to "(...) exceptional problems." The autofilter would, as I mentioned elsewhere, do the opposite of what you mention there. The rest of the answer seems to read as "I disagree. Well, maybe on a case by case basis there could be something, but I would disagree too probably."

Comment: You never justify why you disagree with a list. You only justify why moderators shouldn't handle it manually, which is again not the topic in question. In fact, saying that moderators shouldn't handle it manually is arguably a point *in favor* to the idea of a blacklist.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I added some words to address your concerns.

Comment: You insist that "the algorithm" must be allowed to decide, an algorithm that was devised by humans (by the way, do you know what it does?). These humans decided at some points that this algorithme will filter out every question from our site whose title contains the symbol $. Now, we are discussing whether we might ask those same humans to modify the algorithm to filter out based on something else. Why is it better that we do not participate in the fine tuning of the algorithm?

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks. So you think that the algorithm does a fine job by itself? More precisely, you think that (with probability close to one) there are *no* filters that the community could do that would improve the algorithm's selections? That seems a bold claim, since the algorithm is devised for use in a wide array of different sites with different needs. I find it realistic for someone to defend few or very specific words. But no words seems quite unrealistic and an ideological standpoint with no pragmatic basis.

Comment: @MattSamuel The algorithm was done by people. Its selection criteria devised by people at some point, it is not god sent. People which, most likely, have far lesser insight in to what might be mathematically positive or not to be displayed than the community of a mathematics website. And the best course of action is to leave it as is?

Comment: @quid I personally don't think MathJax should be filtered out, but as far as I know we have no control over that, so I don't argue with that. I can't reasonably get behind there being a list of regular expressions to filter out when these suggestions are the ones that are given. I can't think of anything that actually should be filtered out, including, in my opinion, MathJax, which I think was filtered out due to reluctance to have MathJax rendered in the list of links.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo As far as I know the algorithm does not work by selecting questions containing or excluding certain words. It is based on types of activity that happen in a certain timeframe, which are aggregated to form a score, and once the score gets over a certain threshold the question appears on the list, depending on the level of activity of the site as well as certain site specific penalties. That does not seem to be at all site specific to me. There's no natural language processing going on in this process.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo It's been longer than 5 minutes since I posted that comment, but I wanted to edit it to indicate that I don't see any reason why the algorithm should work better on one site as opposed to another. It doesn't depend on the content of the question.

Comment: I think it was more reluctance to have unsightly non-rendered code in the list (and the technical problem of rendering it everywhere). Basically the decision was "This looks ugly. It most go." Some site got banned from the HNQ entirely since their titles were considered as detrimental to the image of the platform. Basically the algorithm includes "exclude all from site x *comment: empirically we found the tiles of site x are bad to have on  SO and alike*" It's a stretch but not entirely impossible that somebody would globally decide to ban some words we proposed.

Comment: If other websites are using the filters, how does that change your opinion with regards to the HNQ? If the one you see is not "purely selected by the algorithm", why should we be excluded from the process?

Comment: @AsafKaragila There's the worn out metaphor that seems to apply of not jumping off a bridge just because everyone else is doing it.

Comment: @Matt: Indeed. If I see a bunch of bridge engineers who have knowledge of the bridge's structural integrity, as well as the pros and cons of actually jumping off the bridge, and they still decide to jump... well, I might jump too. My point here is that you and others on this page keep talking about the HNQ as if it's somehow infallible and was working fine for years, but the algorithm was completely revised last year, and you don't know if other sites are using these filters. The HNQ, as you perceive it, at this point, is predicated on assumptions which are not entirely well-founded.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Let's say I agree there should be filters. What should be filtered out? Something that would identify the question as spam or something to that effect. Your list of words excludes mostly elementary questions which could be perfectly good. And I don't intend to focus on them being elementary either; even if they aren't, titles of perfectly good questions could contain those words. Continued...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Your insistence that the titles should contain MathJax instead of these words is heavily biased in that you have a strong preference for most questions not to be on the hot network questions list, given your aggressive use of the removal feature.

Comment: @Matt: My goal is not to filter out elementary questions, and I wish people would stop making this nonsense claim. My goal is to filter out what I repeatedly see as *bad* questions or questions with *truly terrible titles*. Yes, it is true, most terrible titles are given to elementary questions, but then again, most questions are elementary, and most non-elementary questions are asked by people who are familiar with $\rm\LaTeX$. If I were to edit all these titles, and just so happen to include $\rm\LaTeX$ in them, would that be better?

Comment: @AsafKaragila No. I had a strong feeling you would answer this way based on history; I tried to stave off this response by saying I'm not focused on them being elementary.  Some other sites think titles should avoid MathJax, even if they have MathJax enabled (I've seen this on meta on several sites). I don't think it's wrong to maybe include an equation in the title that doesn't look so bad without MathJax to prevent it being automatically excluded from the list. "How do you solve x+5=32?" looks fine, and doesn't need to be typeset with MathJax.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this approach. I also think that the "avoid MathJax in titles" (e.g. in MathOverflow) came from a past era, where everything was slower, and avoiding JS-heavy code was preferred. This is not really the case anymore. And besides the subjective style of "x+5=32" vs. $x+5=32$, the latter is marked as mathematical content which also helps screen readers and automatic content parsing. But yeah, just to have a few more questions on HNQ, why bother, am I right?

Comment: @MattSamuel independent to what other sites do, the point is though this site does not, and this site also gives warnings against certain titles. It is maybe not an outlandish idea not to put titles on display that violate the existing guidelines for titles.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In any case, where are we leaning in this decision? The most highly upvoted answer states that we shouldn't have a filter list, The answer that clearly states that there should be a list, regardless of its composition, has a score of $0$.

Comment: @Matt: And the question itself got a lot of votes. I am somewhat disappointed by the outcome, yes. I also know that I follow the HNQ *far closer* than most people on the site. And maybe I care about how this site is perceived by others because I am an academic who is using his real name. But I **hate** the idea that this becomes a dumping ground for bad questions, and I refuse to let the HNQ represent that. I don't know why so many people are so in favour of letting an algorithm make these calls, knowing how skewed they tend to be.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Perhaps the voters against having a filter don't think these most of these questions are so bad, just as I don't. You seem to imply with your arguments that you mostly edit titles to improve them when you remove questions from the list. Why, then, did you remove this one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582187/can-i-solve-this-other-than-using-newtons-sums-or-newtons-identities

Comment: @Matt: Because I don't think it's a well presented question, and I don't think it's a well-written one. Yes, it got some very nice answers. If only some of the people would bother to improve the question as well, maybe the questions wouldn't have gone through all of these deletion/undeletion cycles either.

Comment: The comment you make on the voting is more than a bit strange. Votes clearly split about evenly. The answer that says "there should be a list" is at +9/-9 (with the poster also being in favor) so +10/-9; the one for "the proposed  list" is at +11/-12 with the poster likely against so +11/-13. This one  here that mixes together all kinds of things is at +8/-6 now, but to say therefore there is most support against the list is not a reasonable interpretation of the data I think. Anyway you'll see soon how we move forward.

Comment: For example, I think there ought to be some people that are of the opinion that moderators should not remove at will, but there could well be a list. How do they vote on your question? Chances are "up".

Comment: @MattSamuel Indeed, I think would be better if you split your answer into two parts: _against the filter_ and another for _moderators should not remove at will_. One might have different votes for both

Comment: @quid I'm looking mostly at Theo Bendit's answer, which is +23/-14 (by your measure). I suppose though that it is mostly against the proposed list, as I am. I think though that if we think some terms should be filtered out of hot network questions, then they should be bad enough to filter out of all questions, and we might as well put them on the blacklist. Given that we don't actually have a blacklist and just have warnings, it seems that we don't think anything is quite that bad.

Comment: @Matt: It seems to me that you think that we, the community and the moderators, have direct access to the code. That we can just say "hey, let's blacklist", and a week later, it gets pushed to the website's live code. That's not how it works. We have the tools that we are given. Saying that we don't have a blacklist implies that we are okay with everything is quite a contortion of reality.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Regarding the OP from Matt's link above, why did you remove also their other HNQ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3615378/12-men-can-finish-a-job-in-16-days-5-men-work-at-the-start-and-after-8-d

Comment: @Magic_Isa: To ensure there are no rollback on amWhy's edit. (Yes, this happened before that users rolled back edits for the sole reason of getting votes from answering HNQ questions.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila You said there were no abuses of MathJax to remove questions from the HNQ list. That example there is one. There's absolutely no need to use MathJax when the only math in the title is numbers, and the only possible reason is to remove it from the HNQ list.

Comment: @Matt: This was discussed before, repeatedly, and the votes swung towards "math should be math when it is math". So no, this is not an abuse.

Comment: I think that if the question was selected to be on the HNQ (like in the case above, the question IMO was _good_), one should respect it. Once it's off the HNQ, one might come back to add the MathJax.

Comment: I see. I had forgot about that one. I agree that it is not directly against a list. The reasoning you give that if we don't block it entirely it's not so bad is again strange. If there is a hard filter people won't be able to post at all and might go away there question never been seen, even though it could've been fixed. I mean that's also a relevant point. If you want the questions on the HNQ so fix their title. Easy. Double win.

Comment: @Asaf Please shows us data supporting your unfounded claim that "this was discussed before, repeatedly, and the votes swung towards "math should be math when it is math", esp. data pertinent to the cited case.

Comment: @Magic_Isa: Every awful question that gets terrible answers quickly and these get votes quickly goes on the HNQ. The algorithm is not above reason. I don't understand why people keep blackboxing it into a deity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Removing questions from the list is supposed to be done sparingly. Clearly SO expects the algorithm to be respected.

Comment: @Matt: We are **not** SO. Also nobody asked for *our* input when designing the algorithm. Why would you expect the algorithm to be good for *us*?

Comment: @Asaf The company changed their name from SE to SO. I didn't mean SO the site, they hardly ever get questions on the list. The algorithm was not designed for any specific site, if it works for them why shouldn't it work for us?

Comment: @AsafKaragila noo.. afaik most of the time that's not how it is. If this would be the case for the HNQ, don't you think that people would be downvoting severely instead of upvoting severely?

Comment: @Asaf The tour of the site says high quality answers are upvoted and rise to the top. If you don't trust the voting habits of the community and think you always know better, you're being a dictator of content, not a moderator.

Comment: @Matt: Again, we are not the company. We were not consulted, we were not advised. We were given tools. I am also not sure why you think we are *content* moderators. This comes up in every elections, moderators are not here to moderate *content*. We are here to moderate the *community*.

Answer (score -13):

Please consider **upvoting** this post if you agree with having the filter for the HNQ & by removing *only* the following words in list. Else **downvote**.

- question
- the following
- urgent
- opinion
- please
- help

(Feel free to suggest more words to be removed from the HNQ, they might be taking into consideration for the creation of a *new* list (new poll post)).

Comment: See, now this is a problem with your comment. Suppose that I vote this up now, yes? And tomorrow someone suggests that "the following" should stay in the filtered list, and you agree and amend this list. Now I voted on removing "the following", but now it seems that I voted to keep it. So what's the alternative, then? We start a new poll on each amendment?

Comment: @lonestudent ?.

Comment: So the plan is to essentially fill this page with answers to the point where any reasonable discussion is impossible instead of first seeing if there is a support of a list?

Comment: @AsafKaragila how would be difficult to see which one has more upvotes?

Comment: @lonestudent then why would they downvote :), that's not nice.

Comment: @Magic_Isa: Because if I upvote your answer, but then tomorrow I realise that "opinion" should be filtered out, then we either need to edit your post, which we agreed is a bad thing; or post a new one, but then my vote is still counted on your post, so what is it really?

Comment: @AsafKaragila ah. you're right. You could tell me then, and I edit so you can change your vote

Comment: I don't know now, what's best? idk what's more practical idk

Comment: And what about people who voted your answer, but didn't bother to check again, or came back three days later and found 10 more optional lists? No, I don't think they are going to sit through them and vote on them. If anything, it is better to have a separate answer for each word, and another answer for "No autofilters, thank you". Again, this is why I didn't want to rush into polling before ironing out the details.

Comment: @AsafKaragila oh ok, so now voting on words.. no chunks  nor lists, words. ok.

Comment: Chunks are similar to words, voting on a chunk (say, 3-4 words) you can then have comments that let you vote on individual words below it. With a list of 17 words, that would amount to 4-5 chunks, and will ultimately be more orderly.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think the 'votes on the comments for the words' it's not a good idea. Just look, how many comments are all around all the posts.. no way it's gonna be clear, the opposite, confusing

Comment: If only there was some policy of comment removal below these polling answers... huh.

Comment: Also: pls, plz and their uppercase of all of them

Comment: I've to say that this answer, mine:), has $-12$ _very well deserved_ downvotes. I regret including some words.