# Which words (if any) in the title of a question should prevent inclusion in the HNQ list?

Tags: discussion, big-list, hot-questions-list

In a recent post [Autofilters for Hot Network Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31425/autofilters-for-hot-network-questions) the possibility was raised to created a list of words which when contained in a title of a question would prevent the question from being included in the HNQ list. The question can still exist on the site, only inclusion in HNQ list is prevented. Moreover, editing the title to remove the word would lift the block. I will refer to this list as the HNQ block-list.

In the other question various points of view were raised and some voting on the proposal happened. However, voting on a proposal turned out to be complex as there were many aspects: some did not want a HNQ block-list at all, some wanted it as proposed and even more, some maybe wanted or would not mind some words but not what was proposed, others wanted a list but only a short one and without that being guaranteed in advance rather would lobby for none, etc., etc.

No clear community-opinion can be extracted from that. With that in mind lets start from the start.

Everybody that thinks **a particular word** should be included in such a list posts an answer containing this word (below is a template for clarity and to get past the character limit). Up vote on the answer means "I want this on the HNQ block-list", downvote means "I do not want this on the HNQ  block-list".

Only one word per answer, if you have more than one proposal, post several answers (but see the no flooding rule below).

If there are words that emerge as being widely believed to desirable or at least non-problematic to include on such a list, we go forward with the idea and make the list with those words. If no such words emerge, then there will be no list.

Some rules for posting answers:

- Only use the template or something directly equivalent, and **do not include commentary in the answer** as it will invite discussion (this  includes search queries, lists of example posts, etc.) Short neutral and completely uncontroversial explanations are authorized (e.g., expansion of an acronym or abreviation).  If you want to discuss or explain something see [Discussion around voting on what words should be on the HNQ block-list](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31481/discussion-around-voting-on-what-words-should-be-on-the-hnq-block-list) and follow the instructions there.
- Keep comments on answers to a minimum. See [Discussion around voting on what words should be on the HNQ block-list](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31481/discussion-around-voting-on-what-words-should-be-on-the-hnq-block-list) for how to comment on a proposal. You can also use the dedicated chat on the [HNQ block-list](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106667/discussion-about-the-hnq-block-list-voting-for-math-se)
- Do not include minor variants, or spelling variants (neither in the answer nor as separate answer), we can discuss such details later.
- Strive to make realistic proposals. For example, there is no need to include outright vulgarity on the list that anyway would be edited right away. There is also not need to include things that are too niche.
- Do not flood this thread.  At least for the first week, at most two answers per user, per day (to be precise per UTC day).

Once there are many answers we can create a list of answers for better overview. For now please do not create such a list and do not post any other type of answer. Also, try to vote on each word by its merits and avoid bulk-voting (either way).

This thread will be tightly moderated and I will clean up comments frequently. If you want to discuss whatever aspect of it, there is no shortage of possibilities there is a dedicated thread and a dedicated chat (see above) and you can create still more if needed. This thread is for voting, and usually there is no tolerance for campaigning in the voting offices.

---

Template:

`I propose the following word`

`**{insert word}**`

`for inclusion in the HNQ block-list.`

`Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion. Down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.`

Comment: There is some discussion in the chat room by now. Some comments were copied there. Comments here, as announced, will be trimmed persistently.

Comment: I see that many of the answers are now shown as "status-completed'.  What, precisely, does this mean?

Comment: @XanderHenderson "If there are words that emerge as being widely believed to desirable or at least non-problematic to include on such a list, we go forward with the idea and make the list with those words." This is what was completed. Less indirectly, the words in these answers were included in the list.

Comment: Groovy.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @XanderHenderson maybe that answer is more detailed https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32304

Comment: Thanks.  I had noticed that the linked question had been bumped, but did not see the new answer.

Answer (score 49):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I propose the following word

**urgent**

for inclusion in the HNQ block-list.

Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion. Down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Comment: As detailed in comments on main, this would also cover "urgently" which should be non controversial as variant.

Answer (score 47):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I propose the following word (acronym)

**ASAP** $\quad$ ("As soon as possible!")

for inclusion in the HNQ block-list.

Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion. Down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Answer (score 28):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I propose the following word

**please**

for inclusion in the HNQ block-list.

Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion. Down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Answer (score 25):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I propose the following word

**pls**

for inclusion in the HNQ block-list.

Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion. Down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Answer (score 16):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I propose the following word

**help**

for inclusion in the HNQ block-list.

Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion. Down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Comment: For discussion on this proposal see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31488

Answer (score 5):

This answer proposes the following word for inclusion in the HNQ block-list:

**opinion**

Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion. Down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Answer (score 2):

I propose the word "**confused**" for inclusion in the HNQ block-list. Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion, and down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Comment: For discussion on this proposal see: http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31481/discussion-around-voting-on-what-words-should-be-on-the-hnq-block-list/31486#31486

Answer (score 2):

I propose the word

**tricky**

for inclusion in the HNQ block-list.

Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion, and down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Comment: For discussion on this proposal see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31481/discussion-around-voting-on-what-words-should-be-on-the-hnq-block-list/31487#31487

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following word

**Kindly**

for inclusion in the HNQ block-list.

Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion. Down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Answer (score -6):

I propose the following word

**curious**

for inclusion in the HNQ block-list.

Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion. Down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Answer (score -8):

I propose the following word

**trick**

for inclusion in the HNQ block-list.

Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion. Down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Comment: Reposted separately from "tricky."

Answer (score -13):

I propose the following word

**question**

for inclusion in the HNQ block-list.

Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion. Down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Answer (score -15):

I propose the word

**interesting**

for inclusion in the HNQ block-list. Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion, and down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Answer (score -20):

I propose the following word

**this**

for inclusion in the HNQ block-list.

Please up-vote if you agree with the inclusion. Down-vote if you disagree with the inclusion.

Comment: Discussion can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31489/).