# Discussion around voting on what words should be on the HNQ block-list

Tags: discussion, big-list, hot-questions-list

This post is to accompany:

[Which words (if any) in the title of a question should prevent inclusion in the HNQ list?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/which-words-if-any-in-the-title-of-a-question-should-prevent-inclusion-in-the)

If you want to discuss the merits of a word please create an answer for it yet write up your thoughts as a **comment** there. The answer post should be neutral (see the template at the end). (Note the thread is CW and owner-ship of answers posts is unclear; comments stay with the author.) If an answer for the word already exists you can contribute a comment there.

It can make sense to link to that answer as a comment on the other thread.

**Only** provide the link and the remark discussion should happen there. Always link to the answer.

Also include the word in the list here and add a link to the answer.

If any of this should be tricky, leave a comment and I'll take care of it.

List of discussions.

- [advice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31482/)
- [confused](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31486/9003)
- [help](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31488/)
- [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31489/)
- [please](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31485/9003)
- [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31492/9003)

For general discussions you can also use chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106667/discussion-about-the-hnq-block-list-voting-for-math-se

Template:

`This answer was created to discuss reasons for or against the inclusion of **{insert word}** in the HNQ block-list. Please leave your opinion in a comment.`

**Note:** While everybody can do as they please, I would like to state that I don't see much reason to downvote answers in *this* thread here. One could also say that this cuts both ways and there is no reason for me to bring it up, **but** at score -3 answers get grayed out and things become hard to read so there is some practical disadvantage to having low-scoring answers.

Comment: @quid  Can you suggest a limit for the number of "answers for discussion" posted in one day here, by any one user.  I'm afraid one user is attempting to dominate the discussion.

Comment: @amWhy I did not impose a limit here as there is an implicit regulation by the restriction in the other thread. That said, I would appreciate if users do not go overboard. Still I will stop short of imposing a limit on the answers, also because the answer post is just a neutral hook and the actual discourse is in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

This answer was created to discuss aspects of the inclusion of **advice** in the HNQ block-list. Please leave your opinion in a comment.

Comment: The site *used* to accept general advice questions in the past. But we have moved past "advice", and while you can still find many questions about advice, and a lot of them were well-received at the time, as a whole, this is off-topic now (one of the off-topic closure reasons is "seeking advice"). There is absolutely no reason for this to be on the HNQ if it is, as a whole, off topic.

Comment: I will just add that the site still gets quite a few questions tagged ([tag:advice]): https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1224998/number-of-questions-answers-per-month-of-questions-creationdate-in-the-given-tag?tagname=advice#graph

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Please remember that this is a word proposed, if it occurs in the title, to be blocked from the HNQ.  It would not blacklist posts with "advice" in the title from appearing on math.se.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks, I am in favor of not blocklist this word in the HNQ. My [reason](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice?tab=Votes)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice?tab=Newest is a good counterargument, @Magic_Isa

Comment: @AsafKaragila: We see that there are a few [closed] here and there _but_ there are also upvoted and not-closed-questions. Tell me, what's the harm with this word?

Comment: @Magic_Isa: Have you read my first comment? It doesn't seem so.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I have read it. That doesn't answer my question

Comment: @Magic_Isa: Advice questions are off topic. They used to be allowed, and they were very popular. Which is why I say that the date on the question is.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: If they are off topic now, why haven't you removed the tag `advice`? Why haven't you close _all_ of the questions with the 'advice' tag? Why don't users close all of them? // Answer: Because they're not problematic, most of the time are helpful.

Comment: @Magic_Isa: So by that logic, any user we have no deleted entirely is not a problematic user! Why should anyone ever bother flagging offensive comments, then?

Comment: @Magic_Isa Because the rules are different back then, we shouldn't apply present standard to the past.

Answer (score 3):

This answer was created to discuss aspects of the inclusion of **confused** in the HNQ block-list. Please leave your opinion in a comment.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in having this, 100% popular word in Mathematics, in the HNQ list :)

Comment: I'm in favor of removing this word from the list---it is essentially contentless, and adds nothing in terms of clarity about what an asker is asking.  If they weren't confused, they wouldn't be asking a quesiton,

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Am I reading you correctly that the word should not be allowed in a title of a HNQ post because it does not add anything to the question? I ask because the post is asking about the block-list, not the HNQ list.

Comment: Titles should describe the question. Not the motivation, source, or otherwise emotions related to the question. Being confused tells me nothing about the question, and it is irrelevant.

Comment: @user21820  The title of this post refers the HNQ block-list.

Comment: @amWhy: I was asking Xander to clarify it, because there are two lists talked about here. It seems that Magic_Isa does not see anything wrong with allowing this word on the HNQ list, but Xander is in favour of removing it from the HNQ list. However, the question and this answer is talking about the block-list.

Comment: The HNQ blocklist, @user21820  One and the same, not two lists.

Comment: No; see Magic_Isa's first comment with the phrase "HNQ list".

Comment: @user21820 ah I think it should say: "This answer was created to discuss aspects of the -inclusion or not inclusion- of **confused** in the HNQ block-list."

Comment: @Magic_Isa: You yourself used "HNQ list" in your comment. Why don't you be more straightforward and say you do not support having "confused" in the block-list? **And why?**

Comment: Indeed, @user21820, I'm quite sure Xander meant it should be blocked, when it appears in titles, from the HNQ.  Please try to be more clear and precise, Magic.

Comment: @Magic  Define what you mean when you say that '"confused" is a 100% popular word in Mathematics'?

Comment: @user21820 Let me clarify, since I was not at all clear in the first place.  I think that titles containing "confused" should be removed from the HNQ list, and hence the word "confused" should be on the list of verboten words.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Extra ping for @amWhy, as she was a part of the conversasion.  Magic_Isa should have been automatically pinged, as they are the author of the post.

Comment: Well, what one say when one doesn't know? "I am confused.." It's very common to say this, like automatically, so please don't exclude it from the HNQ

Comment: @Magic_Isa: We want to tell people "Hey, look at this great content", and we want to educate by example of how great content should be presented. You're not willing to compromise on the quality of the question, why are you so quick to compromise on the quality of the titles?

Comment: @AsafKaragila "You're not willing to compromise on the quality of the question" excuse me?

Answer (score 2):

This answer was created to discuss aspects of the inclusion of **tricky** in the HNQ block-list. Please leave your opinion in a comment.

Comment: For example, see this famous question [Suspension of a product - tricky homotopy equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301402/suspension-of-a-product-tricky-homotopy-equivalence)

Comment: For example, there are countless deleted posts including the word "tricky", which, since deleted, would not come up in Magic_Isa's search. The ones that remain are not representative of the widespread abuse of this word in titles, as it is sometimes used as click-bait.  It is also a very subjective word, like "hard", "simple"

Comment: Remember, we are not talking about banning posts from math.se; rather words in titles that suggest they are not good candidates for the HNQ.

Comment: "which, since deleted, would not come up in Magic_Isa's search"  :(

Comment: I'm glad you read my comment, @Magic_Isa.  :-)

Comment: Titles should describe the question. Not the motivation, source, or otherwise emotions related to the question. Something being "tricky" tells us nothing about the actual question and it is irrelevant as a whole to the title.

Comment: "The ones that remain are not representative of the widespread abuse of this word in titles" well, one needs to provide a proof to see this, or well at least a sketch of the proof.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was created to discuss aspects of the inclusion of [**help**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31478/9003) in the HNQ block-list. Please leave your opinion in a comment

Comment: See for example, this extremely famous question [Help with a prime number spiral which turns 90 degrees at each prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072308/help-with-a-prime-number-spiral-which-turns-90-degrees-at-each-prime)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this word, this could be allowed in the HNQ. Although the format and guidelines of this site is _question_, _answer_ and Bye. It's very natural to say 'help', 'help me', etc. along with a well written question

Comment: Titles should describe the question. Not the motivation, source, or otherwise emotions related to the question. Yes, you need help. This is why you're asking a question. This is entirely irrelevant to the question to begin with.

Comment: What if the title states nothing but "Please Help with this!", Magic_Isa ?  It seems you are focusing on locating only the very few exceptions, and otherwise turning a blind eye to the many abuses and over uses of terms proposed for the HNQ block-list. As @Asaf suggested in his original post about filters for the HNQ, it is far easier to edit the title(s) of an exception or two, than to manually have to remove hundreds of other poor posts with very poor titles.

Comment: I see your point. Yes, there are good and bad questions titles with the word 'help'. It's just that, for me, isn't that fair to not to allow a _good_ question to be on the HNQ just because it's "banned" due the inclusion of the word 'help' in their title.

Comment: But it's fair to not allow a *good* question to be on the HNQ just because it's "banned" due to having MathJax in the title?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's also unfair, actually very very unfair. IIRC you said that there's not much that one could do to fix the MathJax thing. But let's focus on 'help' word here, yes?

Comment: @Magic_Isa: Yes, but how is the word "help" is *helpful* to me, as a reader, when I see a title with the word "help" (with a few obvious exceptions such as "how many permutations of the word HELP start with H?"), how is this title conveying any information? And wouldn't it be better if the HNQ had questions with better titles *instead*? Wouldn't it be great if users like yourself would simply *edit* the title when they see "help" so that the undoubtedly great question therein can have a great title too?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, some people see it like unhelpful in the title as 'tells nothing'; for some others is the opposite. "Help me to understand the definition of measurable function" vs "Understanding the definition of measurable function", which one would one pick? // both are ok

Comment: @Magic_Isa Perhaps both are okay, but the second is better.  An even better title might be something like "Understanding Folland's definition of a Borel measurable function."  If you eliminate uninformative words like "help", you get a few extra characters to add more context.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Is the second better then.. hmm well it is but for _some_ people. I think someone hasn't seen my first comments (with the link)

Comment: What context or information is conveyed by the words "Help me to" in the title?  They are asking a question on MSE, so it should be obvious that they require help.  How is the title in any way improved by adding those words?

Comment: The discussion is about whether "help" in the title should disqualify a question from being in HNQ. The discussion is **not** about whether question writers should include "help" in their titles.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: If we want question on the HNQ to be descriptive and informative, then to some extent the discussion *should* overlap with whether or not you should include the word "help" in the title of a question.

Comment: Disallowing questions based on keywords seems like an extraordinarily clunky method

Comment: @Zubin: That is a discussion for a different thread. But you should perhaps suggest a better way to deal with this when you bring it up.

Comment: Here is what I am thinking: 

Most poorly titled questions already will never make it to HNQ, because they won't receive the votes and attention that are necessary to make it to HNQ. I suspect that a poorly titled question could only make it to HNQ if it was exceptionally interesting. In that case, the best solution is not to disallow that interesting question from HNQ, but rather to revise its title.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: That is an extremely naive approach to how the site is actually being run. Low quality questions get votes all the time; people tend to forget to edit titles.

Comment: I guess the question is: **What proportion of [questions with bad titles] that are also [questions that get enough votes to make HNQ] are also [questions that should not be on HNQ]?** I went to the top questions of the month and found a few with terrible titles, for example this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3602668/spivak-chapter-10-problem-29-why-is-this-true To me, this seems like a question that is a good question, but has a terrible title ... maybe I am misunderstanding the point of HNQ - are good questions with bad titles supposed to be excluded from there?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: (1) This is one of the reasons I want "this" filtered out, yes. (2) Yes, good questions can be *eligible* if they have their titles edited to be informative and good. So we want to create a filter that catches mostly bad titles. We are allowed to showcase at most 5 questions at a time, why not insist that every details in those posts is perfect? That starts with the title.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was created to discuss aspects of the inclusion of [**please**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31485/515527) in the HNQ block-list.

Comment: Titles should describe the question. Not the motivation, source, or otherwise emotions related to the question, nor appealing to users' good-will, by asking "please". If you need to say "please", do so in the body of the post, but not in the title. When it is used in the title it is entirely irrelevant to the question to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was created to discuss aspects of the inclusion of [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31484/9003) in the HNQ block-list.

Comment: I think any title with "question" included in it is redundant, as math.se, like all SE sites, are explicitly question and answer sites.  Including "question about...." is just as redundant as if an answer began with "answer about...".  Titles should describe the question, and not refer to the question as "a question" which isn't described in the title.

Comment: I agree, but this is a little contentious because as a non-native speaker, many are taught that redundancy is polite, especially when asking things of authorities (which many users view meta users as). I am not in favor of blacklisting question.

Comment: This thread, @DonThousand, is not about the blacklisting of questions.

Comment: Regardless, my comment holds.

Comment: @DonThousand I didn't know that, had I know I'd have not proposed the word to be on the blocklist... but so far we are good:) currently has -11 downvotes, so no way it will be removed from the HNQ

Answer (score -1):

This answer was created to discuss aspects of the inclusion of **this** in the HNQ block-list. Please leave your opinion in a comment.

Comment: The word "this" is *usually* vague. It usually a stand-in for the actual content of the question, and it is *usually* the case that it can be replaced by a short description of the question instead. Titles, in general, should be descriptive. If we want the HNQ to publicise and promote good content, we should strive to put this standard towards titles as well. The word "this" is *usually* not up to par.

Comment: @Magic_Isa: Exactly.

Comment: Asaf, I am 100% against having **this** in the blocklist

Comment: @Magic_Isa: Interesting, because you gave an absolutely fantastic justification why *this* should not be allowed on the HNQ.

Comment: hmm, that was not my intention. I am gonna edit then

Comment: All the more reason, @Magic_Isa, for you to take more time to consider your positions, articulate them well, rather than posting the first gut reaction you have to meta matters.

Comment: well I can't find a nice example, because indeed I know nothing about set theory, but I am sure there're thousands with the word _this_ included on many set theory famous question

Comment: @Magic_Isa: Yes, *some* questions have a reasonable use of "this" in the title. I am talking about what I've seen in cases on the HNQ.

Comment: What you don't understand, @Magic, is that you're conflating "popular/highly-upvoted/famous" with "high-quality".  The two are not necessarily equivalent.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: See this [Why does this innovative method of subtraction from a third grader always work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667980/why-does-this-innovative-method-of-subtraction-from-a-third-grader-always-work) // psst I won't 'bother' more :) just that link.

Comment: @Magic_Isa "Why does my third grader's method for subtraction always work?"  Such a title avoids use of the word this, is more compact, and more clearly explains the content of the post.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Right, but most users won't know that they are being blocked from HNQ because of **this**.

Comment: @DonThousand Honestly, I am not all that concerned by that.  The original title, with the word "this" is clickbaity---what "this" is remains mostly unspecified.  I don't think that MSE ought to be advertising itself with clickbait.  I think that my version of the title is still pretty clickbaity (the question itself is kind of clickbait), but it gives a better idea of the content, allowing a user to decide whether or not to click with sufficient information to know if they are wasting their time or not.

Comment: @DonThousand: Do you think most people even know that MathJax blocks them from the HNQ? Do you think that it *should* even matter for quality concerns?

Comment: I'm a bit torn. "How to solve this equation" is certainly a bad title, but I think there are cases like Magic_Isa's second example where the use of "this" makes sense in a title and it would be the most natural way to write the title. I realise that a certain amount of false negatives is probably unavoidable, but including such relatively common words seems a bit overzealous to me.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I'm not terribly interested in clicking on a title that says "How to solve this equation" which is a generic title that could be applied to 100,000 questions.

Comment: @ArnaudD. What about other *good* questions that deserve to be on the HNQ, and were not selected because of a mediocre to bad title?

Comment: @amWhy As I said, "How to solve this equation" is certainly a bad title, and it should absolutely be edited (I find these titles particularly annoying when I look through "Related Questions" to find a duplicate). But for example,[There are apparently 3072 ways to draw this flower. But why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736483/there-are-apparently-3072-ways-to-draw-this-flower-but-why) seems like a reasonable and natural use to me, for a question that I wouldn't mind seeing on the HNQ (I think it was there, at the time ; at least it was tweeted, according to the Edit History).

Comment: @ArnaudD.: Yes, of course there are going to be *some* questions that are decent. But there are *so many more that are not*. And for each one that is not that ends on the HNQ takes a spot of an actual good question. And until they are removed manually, they will stay there. We can't accommodate *everything*, and at some point, hard choices needs to be made.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So for each decent titles with "this", how many indecent title with "this" are?