# Do we, the community, need a HNQ block list?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions-list

### Short Version

The purpose of this post is to have a vote count of the community support/opposition of the recent HNQ block list proposal. If you don't want to read the long version of the post then please go directly to **Aim of this post** and vote accordingly.

### Long Version

In the last couple of weeks there has been an effort from the mod team about a the creation of a possible list of words (or phrases) that will filter questions out of the HNQ list (see [Autofilters for Hot Network Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31425/autofilters-for-hot-network-questions/31444#31444), [Which words (if any) in the title of a question should prevent inclusion in the HNQ list?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/which-words-if-any-in-the-title-of-a-question-should-prevent-inclusion-in-the) and [Discussion around voting on what words should be on the HNQ block-list](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31481/discussion-around-voting-on-what-words-should-be-on-the-hnq-block-list) for more details). This list, heceforth, I will refer to as HNQ block list.

In the post [Autofilters for Hot Network Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31425/autofilters-for-hot-network-questions/31444#31444), the response of the community has been very much mixed and no conclusion could be drawn about the support or opposition of the community regarding the creation of such a list. One reason for this, I believe, was that the central question was not precisely asked. To be more precise, we were not **directly** asked whether we really need a HNQ block list. For this purpose, I posted [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31444/170039). But I have been told,

> This is ultimately unhelpful. We can change the list, it's not a one-off request. So the question should first be, is there a community support for *a* list. Then we start weeding things out of the proposed list in the post itself. – Asaf Karagila♦ Apr 7 at 18:04
>
> @AsafKaragila: In that case I don't understand how this can be unhelpful. Can you be more specific? For example, you wrote, "So the question should first be, is there a community support for a list.". Why not edit the question to include only *this* and see how it goes? – user 170039 Apr 8 at 6:18
>
> @user170039: Of the +9 voters, it is unclear, who is just in favour of a filter, and who is also in favour of the list, and who is in favour of *some* part of the list. Similarly for the -9 voters, are they against *all* filtration, or just the word "puzzle", or anything else? – Asaf Karagila♦ Apr 8 at 6:20
>
> @AsafKaragila: Indeed. That's why a rewording is necessary. Otherwise, I don't see much value in this post. – user 170039 Apr 8 at 7:38

Furthermore, in the post [Which words (if any) in the title of a question should prevent inclusion in the HNQ list?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/which-words-if-any-in-the-title-of-a-question-should-prevent-inclusion-in-the), suggestions for inclusion of words in the HNQ block list is asked. While this is definitely a welcome effort, I think, it is a bit rushed. I also metioned this in a comment,

> I would say that this question already presumes that **the community wants a list**. Which was not really established. — user 170039 6 hours ago

**Yes, I have heard that argument that there is already a list, it's just the case that the list is empty (see [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54088874#54088874)). But to me it looks like pointless rhetoric and I am looking for a concrete way to measure the support of the community for the proposal of creation of a non-empty HNQ block list. Note that voting on the answers of the last linked question doesn't really show support/opposition for the creation/need of such a list. It implies that *if* such a list is going to be created *then* $n$ people agree with the proposal of including "[word]" in such a list.**

So we are again back to the same question,

> Do we need a HNQ block list?

### Aim of this Post

It has been argued by the author of [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/which-words-if-any-in-the-title-of-a-question-should-prevent-inclusion-in-the) that the bold part of my text is false. Whereas I do not want to include myself into pointless rhetoric, note that I am not asking whether we **want** a list. I am asking whether we **need** a list or not. There is an important difference here (even though there is an effort to brush it off as "tangential").

Furthermore, the question which is stated to allow the community **to decide if it wants a list via voting on words** has an interesting feature. It seems to me that here that the above mentioned "decision procedure" has already been decided on behalf of the community, but I may of course be wrong. What is most puzzling to me in this whole episode is the following,

> If you want to know whether the community wants/needs a HNQ block list or not, why not ask them directly and wait for their feedback instead of already presuming the process it to be "abstract"?

This poll here is to have a vote count just to get a clear picture of the voice of the community regarding this issue. I will be posting an answer. Please consider upvoting/downvoting it as you see fit. **Please don't post any more answers**.

Comment: There is a list already.  It is not empty. It includes the word `$`.

Comment: I fear with this post you are curtailing the process already underway.  It is unfair to pose this as a "yes/no" wrt HNQ block-list.  Very little in human live is black and white.

Comment: Duplicates: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/which-words-if-any-in-the-title-of-a-question-should-prevent-inclusion-in-the/31474#31474, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31425/autofilters-for-hot-network-questions, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31481/discussion-around-voting-on-what-words-should-be-on-the-hnq-block-list

Comment: Please check the body of the question. All the posts that you have linked are already included in the body of the question.

Comment: It is ultimately **irrelevant** if the "community wants a list" **in abstract**.  That's especially true the other way than you frame it. What would be gained if we agree that we want a list, but then we cannot agree what to put on the list? Whatever one might think on the merits of the idea, I think it is better to establish **first** if there are some words which have support for inclusion.

Comment: Technically the poll procedure is very poor.  "Please consider upvoting/downvoting them as you see fit. [...] please vote only on one answer. " That's not enforceable and not helpful. Usually one says nothing, or limits to considering votes in one direction. As is, if I am against the list,  I can decide to either downvote yes or to upvote no? Of course I could do both and nobody could do much about it, which is why the poll is especially poor.

Comment: @quid: Good point. Thanks.

Comment: @Zacky how is this poll different from "I am in favor of creating a blacklist of terms which will prevent a post from appearing on the HNQ. The precise composition of that list be determined once we have agreed that such a list should exist in the first place."

Comment: Tangentially the exact phrasing is also problematic. Why ask for "need" and not "want" the later is much more to the point. Taken literally I am not even sure I agree that we *need* such a list, we'd get by alright without one. But I want one, I think we should have one, etc. But "need" not really. **For this and other reasons I boycott this vote.**

Comment: @Zacky any chance for a reply? In case it was missed that question was polled already in the dupe target.

Comment: To those voting to reopen this question:  why?  There are already *several* active posts on meta discussing the pros and cons of the HNQ, a potential list of filter words, and how the HNQ should interact with MSE.  What does this question add to the discussion which isn't already being asked elseswhere?

Comment: @Zacky that are comments on a *different* poll though.  There are already (at least) three polls in the other question. The one that is discussed, by OP, that was actually not clear. A second by Magic_Isa that was clear but had a different scope. And then a third one by Xander which had the text I quoted. It is amply clear that this third poll I quote is about the general principle and not any specific list. Thus, I reiterate how is the question here different from the one quoted in *my comment* and that was polled already.

Comment: I think that I will need to respond. There are several active posts on meta "discussing the pros and cons of the HNQ, a potential list of filter words, and how the HNQ should interact with MSE". True. **Note however, that the existence of the first question can't by default make my post irrelevant, simply because the focus of the questions are different. Same argument for the third question.**

Comment: The problem with Xander's answer, in my opinion, is summarized in [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31425/autofilters-for-hot-network-questions#comment138562_31463). It is also interesting to note that in spite of [this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31425/autofilters-for-hot-network-questions#comment138540_31463) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31425/autofilters-for-hot-network-questions#comment138540_31463) there was not attempt either to address or edit the poll.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/under-what-criteria-should-we-remove-questions-from-the-hnq-list?rq=1).

Comment: Maybe a good start would be to get some idea on what the HNQ *should be used for*. Then we can start talking about how adding more automatically blocked words to the list is helpful to achieve that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It's indeed a good idea. There is already a meta post about it written recently. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31508/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions-in-mathematics-stack-exchange).

Comment: Why are you directing my attention to a question I've edited on meta just 15 hours ago? In any case, my point is that when I was set to do this, I thought there was some agreement on what should or shouldn't be on the HNQ. Apparently I was gravely mistaken. So instead of fussing on should we have another poll, should it be clearer or more ambiguous, and should people actually vote or not. Maybe we should first figure out how we want to use this feature. Then we can decide how to implement an autofilter.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: As I said, it's a good idea indeed. But I would prefer to wait a bit more for some answers to the question I linked just now.

Comment: I feel like we're talking past each other. Repeatedly, and throughout everywhere in this multipage discussion.

Comment: Your edit in bold is false and in direct contradiction what is written in that question. I added a note. You can change it as you see fit. But this must be addressed in some way. What you say is demonstrably false from  the text of the other question.

Comment: @quid: I have removed it. If you have something to say, say in the comments or go to chat, I will try to respond if it doesn't take me into pointless rhetoric. I understand where you are coming from, but editing the post to include your objections is something that I didn't know was even possible and permissible. If that's permissible then I would also like to have the courtesy to edit your post.

Comment: You did not know it was possible? What did make you believe that your post was not editable like any other post or do you generally not know that posts can be edited with users with 2k+ points. You put *clear* misinformation in bold in a post. intelectual honesty would dictate that you keep at least the direct quote from the other question, which explains explicitly what is voted on.  Do not twist reality to push your agenda. If you already want to object to something you can object to voting it in this way. What you cannot do, while being intelectually honest, is misrepresent the content.

Comment: There is an overwhelming support via votes **for having a  block-list** that contains "urgent". You do not like that, fine. But that is fact. If you want to claim users did not understand what they are voting for, try to make that argument.  But the vote as I initiated it is on this, and not the if-then scenario you claim. Instead the if-then is if there is support for words, then we will move forward with the idea to implement a list. By now it seems there is support for certain words. Thus, except if this changes drastically, we will move forward.

Comment: To put this differently. Contrary to what you claim the question does not *presume* that community wants a list, instead it allows the community to *decide if it wants a list via voting on words* (and in this way also which list). This is may be not your preferred way to vote this, but **it is false** that it presumes a preference on having a list.

Comment: Since you now embrace the fact that there is a distinction between "need" and "want" could you clarify the meaning of "need" in this context. "This game is so cool. I need to have that." "I did not yet have lunch and it is already middle of the afternoon. I need to eat something." "If  nothing is done I will be dead  by tomorrow. I need this treatment." All kinds of "need"; not quite equivalent. Of course the last is extreme and has no analogue on the site. But already the first two are not really the same and there is a big range here. For many a feature one can say  we do not *need* it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think that we, the community, need a HNQ block list.

Comment: I think that this poll answer, should be proposed once the final _list_ is ready to 'implement', I mean, users are voting now for which words yes and which words no, and at some point there'll be the final list. Then you might ask again: "Implementing the list with this words or simply _no_?"

Comment: Regardless, I think this is a wonderful idea, because me thinks that there'll be a lot of disagreement once the _final list_ is ready to 'implement'

Comment: @Magic_Isa: In that scenario you would be assuming that the community wants a list. It's just not the one which has been "finalized". Why would you be assuming that?

Comment: Because for example, I think we _all_ agree in removing: urgent, pls, ASAP. So yes, we want a list. And say, you don't fully agree but can tolerate another 5 more words. But what would happen if the _final_ lists contains 15 words, which you don't agree with? Would you still want a list?

Comment: @Magic_Isa Yes of course I would still want a list, you even explain this yourself earlier in the comment. I just don't want *that* list.

Comment: @Magic_Isa: I fully agree with Servaes.