# Is there a way to search for past HNQ?

Tags: support, hot-questions-list

Is there a way to search for past "Hot Network Questions"? It would be best if it included those that where removed by moderators for whatever reason)

Given that there is a discussion about HNQ, and their titles, it seems like it would be helpful to actually have a list of previous HNQ (ideally with a quick way to see if titles have been edited too).

Comment: Searching on SEDE for HNQ will turn up various premade queries.  I am sure somebody will give a better answer though.

Comment: Yes, looks like there are quite a few that would answer the question.

Comment: The [meta-tag:search] is for the search feature, rather than the abstract idea of searching in the site.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Alright, thanks

Comment: I will add that HNQs from this site are posted [by this feed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-1077/hnq-math-se?tab=recent) into [Hot and bountied questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/106623) and [by this user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-803/math) into [Hot Network Questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/89485). So if it is preferable in some situations, one could use those chatroom to search among HNQs.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, Stack Exchange data explorer has everything we could want. Here is a [link to searching for HNQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/queries?q=hnq). Some specific scripts are below.

- [Questions which were in HNQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1075209/questions-which-were-in-hnq)
- [Initial title for the questions that were removed from HNQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1102898/initial-title-for-the-questions-that-were-removed-from-hnq?num=100)
- [Initial title for the questions that entered HNQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1102897/initial-title-for-the-questions-that-entered-hnq?num=100)
- [Questions which were in HNQ and were later closed](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1102659/questions-which-were-in-hnq-and-were-later-closed)

Comment: If you are specifically interested in the post removed by mods, you can use some of the queries [mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/64952/2020/4/10). I have also mentioned some queries in another recent discussion [in a comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31425/autofilters-for-hot-network-questions#comment138253_31425).

Comment: And if it helps, here are [a few more random queries](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/sede-queries-related-to-hnqs) related to HNQs.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Feel free to add more to the answer.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the option to search HNQ with SEDE was only added last year. As a result, these queries only return questions that entered the HNQ after February 2019. I'm not sure if there's a way to know which questions were in the HNQ before that.

Comment: I will add some [meta.se] links to @ArnaudD.'s comment: [Please open the Hot Network Questions to auditing via the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286986#324663) and [Now you can know if a question really hit the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324641). And since also mod-removals are discussed here, this possibility exists since March 2019: [Updating the Hot Network Questions List - now with a bit more network and a little less “hotness”!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060).

Comment: @ArnaudD. That is a long enough time frame to start to understand problems and what titles and questions actually look like. Plus standards for math.se change over time so really old results don't mean that much